# HTML é uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: html, característica-linguagem, terminologia

Não é minha intenção trazer a confusão dos outros para o site, porém ficou uma dúvida minha (interna, daquelas coisas que se tem certeza e depois vem alguém e faz uma pergunta que mexe com as certezas antigas). Vi [neste](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/top-10-programming-languages) site, a classificação do Top 10 das linguagens de programação, e notei que para algumas pessoas HTML é uma linguagem de programação e para outras não.

#### Dúvida:

HTML é uma linguagem de programação ou não?

Comment: Olha acredito que não por tudo que li nas respostas aqui e nos links indicados, mas não consideraria um "erro" colocar no currículo na parte de Linguagens de programação porque se nós que somos da area de TI estamos discutindo isso é certo que um RH não terá essa certeza e por falta dessa informação pode achar que você desconhece essa "linguagem de marcação" e tirar você de uma possível entrevista.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

## Não.

Essa é uma dúvida e um erro comum. HTML é uma linguagem de marcação como o próprio nome diz. Hyper Text **Markup Language**. Mais amplamente pode ser considerada uma linguagem de dados. HTML apenas encapsula dados e descreve **o que fazer com eles, não como fazer**. Está [definido na Wikipedia em inglês](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML).

> A web browser can read HTML files and compose them into visible or audible web pages. The browser does not display the HTML tags, but uses them to interpret the content of the page. HTML describes the structure of a website semantically along with cues for presentation, making it a **markup language rather than a programming language**.

Ela não é linguagem de programação porque não é *[Turing complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)*. Ou seja, ela precisaria ter algumas características específicas para poder "programar um dispositivo". Você não pode executar o HTML, por isto é que precisa do JavaScript para fazer algumas coisas, esta sim uma linguagem de programação. Ambas podem até serem consideradas linguagens computacionais, mas para por aí.

Semântica: você programa e/ou codifica em JavaScript mas só codifica em HTML (você cria um código que declara uma forma de apresentação).

## Máquina de Turing

HTML está longe de ter a completude de Turing. Ela precisaria ter **todas** estas capacidades:

- fazer cálculos;
- mudar informações contidas em algum tipo de memória;
- tomar decisões;
- mudar o fluxo de execução.

[Alan Turing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Turing) criou uma [máquina teórica mínima](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) que permite fazer estas operações e passou-se considerar que qualquer linguagem de programação precisa ser capaz de fazer todas as operações desta máquina universal.

Estas linguagens que não são de programação ajudam instruir dispositivos (computadores com softwares, por exemplo) a realizar alguma tarefa, mas uma linguagem de marcação tem sua capacidade de fazer isto bem limitada, não consegue fazer todas operações da máquina de Turing.

Além disto uma linguagem de marcação sozinha não faz nada. Em tese você poderia até criar uma máquina que "entenderia" uma linguagem de marcação e fazer alguma coisa mas duvido que isto teria alguma utilidade real. Na prática, na tecnologia atual, estas linguagens só funcionam porque são interpretadas por softwares que foram criados com... linguagens de programação.

Por que adotamos a máquina de Turing como parâmetro para definir o que é uma linguagem de programação? Você precisa estabelecer um corte, dar uma linha onde tem cada coisa, caso contrário qualquer coisa poderia ser uma linguagem de programação, até mesmo a tabela ASCII pode ser considerada assim porque há um conjunto de regras e o seu uso instrui de forma limitado como um computador deve operar. Pode-se alegar que a definição é arbitrária, mas ela faz sentido, é útil para classificação, foi inventada no início na computação moderna e não traz problemas.

Pode-se inventar outro critério? Claro que pode, mas para que? Existe quem alega que 1 mais 1 não é 2. Pode ser verdade, mas que ganho teremos em mudar este conceito? Como exercício de pensamento pode ser interessante, mas não tem motivação prática, por isso quem insiste nisso beira a insanidade.

A classificação sobre linguagens que se faz hoje atende bem a comunidade. Pessoas que querem questionar são bem-vindas, porém se a pessoa quer mudar o que foi estabelecido e estabelecer uma nova norma, precisa convencer as pessoas, dar dados concretos, mostrar pesquisas sérias que mudam isto e dão motivação para a mudança. Isto é diferente de apenas corrigir um entendimento errado por parte de algumas coisas e que documentos oficiais dizem o contrário, como eu fiz em [Qual a diferença entre atributo e campo, nas classes?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101).

## Outras linguagens

Em geral linguagens que terminam com ML são linguagens de marcação, vide [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). Claro que isto é apenas uma ideia inicial, existe uma linguagem de programação chamada ML (Meta Language) e várias derivadas delas (SML, CAML, OCAML, etc.). Embora não esteja no nome da maioria das linguagens de programação a sigla PL acaba sendo associada a elas de alguma forma. Um caso onde o nome tem a sigla é o [PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL) que obviamente é uma linguagem de programação.

Então SQL deve ser uma linguagem de programação, certo? Não, pelo menos na sua versão ANSI ela não é *Turing complete*. As extensões fornecidas pelos principais sistemas de banco de dados do mercado, principalmente para trabalhar com *stored procedures*, são mais completas e aí sim podem ser consideradas *Turing equivalent* (apenas um nome alternativo/sinônimo).

[CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS) é uma linguagem de estilos e também não é uma linguagem de programação.

Já [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) é uma linguagem declarativa como a maioria das linguagens de marcação mas é uma linguagem de programação já que permite fazer todas computações da máquina abstrata de Turing.

Tanto linguagens de programação quanto de marcação podem ser declarativas ou imperativas. São conceitos diferentes. Pode haver confusão porque é mais comum as PLs serem imperativas e as MLs serem declarativas.

[Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)) é uma PL que é usada como marcação em algumas situações. Claro que é o uso de apenas um *subset*, mas ela pode ser usada como uma forma muito parecida com [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) que também é ML baseada em JavaScript que é uma PL. Certamente existem outras linguagens que possuem uma sintaxe que facilitam ter uso como linguagem de marcação.

Já se considerar HTML5+CSS3 como uma linguagem única aí fica mais complicado dizer se isto pode ser considerada uma linguagem de programação. Certamente seria uma PL bem estranha de usar mas pode fazer todas computações mínimas, certo? Veja a [Rule 110](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_110).

## Por que saber isto é importante?

Porque computação é uma ciência exata, quando você não liga para a exatidão das coisas você está no caminho errado para realizar este trabalho. Além de saber se comunicar melhor com seus pares de profissão (aqui inclusive), há um efeito cognitivo importante quando procura fazer e definir as coisas da maneira correta. Você é reflexo do que você pratica. Ninguém é musculoso sem fazer esforço físico (nem tomando bomba). Ninguém vai se "comunicar com o computador" adequadamente se não exercita a comunicação precisa em tudo na vida. Não estou dizendo que você precisa saber tudo, que não pode errar, o que seria ingênuo, mas precisa se esforçar e ter isto sempre em mente. Desconheço uma chavinha no cérebro que liga ou desliga a capacidade e necessidade de comunicação correta, que só queria ter um compilador para me ajudar indicar meus erros quando não estou programando :) .

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Bom @Maniero percebido (bem vindo ao clube dos que creem nisso), porém, em HTML nós de alguma forma "instruímos ao computador" o que e como mostrar as coisas certo?

Comment: @Cold você faz um desenho e o navegador traduz graficamente. Mas não existem algoritmos em HTML, por exemplo. No dia que alguém conseguir fazer uma soma em HTML, a gente pode conversar sobre ela ser uma linguagem de programação ;)

Comment: BTW +1 pela referência a completude de Turing.

Comment: Excel é uma linguagem de programação (vote aqui se concorda)

Comment: Excel NÃO é uma linguagem de programação (vote aqui se concorda)

Comment: É possível fazer operações matemáticas, armazenar valores, recuperá-los e fazer desvios condicionais em fórmulas do Excel (sem VBA). Isso quer dizer que as fórmulas sao turing-complete?

Comment: Seria Excel a linguagem de programação mais usada no mundo então? rs

Comment: @fernandodelrio pra você não preciso responder :D Mas fica a dúvida para os outros.

Comment: Excel, [mais perigoso que o Stuxnet](http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2013/02/13/microsofts-excel-might-be-the-most-dangerous-software-on-the-planet/).

Comment: Bom, o Miguel Angelo já tinha colocado um link que mostra que Excel pode ser considerado uma linguagem de programação. O que faria ser a linguagem de programação com maior quantidade de usuário no mundo. Apesar de haver evidências que ela possa ter todas as características necessárias para ser considerada assim há quem não concorde https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=429505. Foi curioso ver que a maioria votou que não é.

Comment: Excel não é nem de perto uma linguagem de programação. Até mesmo as formulas são escritas em VBA, é apenas uma transformação para que usuários mais simples pratiquem tudo que o VBA faz por trás de um "Design View" das planilhas, é só isso que é o Excel.

Comment: @biio você precisa se informar melhor, aqui não é espaço para se discutir o assunto mas o que tem na resposta e nos comentários deixam claro que as pessoas que estudam profundamente o assunto consideram que é.

Comment: @Maniero Sim, eu votei 12 vezes no comentário lá em cima, não é mesmo?

Comment: A informação que eu tenho e por tudo o que eu conheço sobre linguagens (e é a área da computação que mais gosto) Excel é uma linguagem de programação. Aceito que existam posições divergentes. Basta postar uma informação embasada que afirme isto com argumentos concretos.

Comment: CSS é uma linguagem de programação? Ela pode fazer cálculos (`calc(5  -3)`), pode mudar informações (`hover`), toma decisões e muda o fluxo de execução (`@media`).

Comment: @Patrick Mas ha limitações, ela não consegue resolver todos tipos de problemas.

Comment: Na época eu votei que acreditava que excel não era linguagem de programação, hoje mudei bastante o meu conceito, e acredito que SIM, excel é uma linguagem de programação

Answer (score 39):

## Não. HTML é uma linguagem de marcação de hiper texto

HTML é uma linguagem de marcação, é utilizada para fins estruturais. HTML encapsula ou marca dados dentro de tags HTML, o navegador então lê e interpreta o conteúdo e consegue exibir diferentemente, títulos, parágrafos, links, tabelas e etc...

HTML não é um script executável, como dito, HTML é utilizado para fins estruturais e não funcionais, portanto **não é uma linguagem de programação**. HTML não contem nenhuma lógica de programação, não é possível criar por exemplo estruturas condicionais como IF/ELSE, não é possível declarar funções ou executar cálculos. Com HTML não é possível manipular ou modificar dados de forma alguma.

**E se alguém insistir, peça-o para fazer um código que calcule 1 + 1 em HTML.**

Comment: kkkk, recomendo dar uma olhada no link que coloquei pro site que "incitou" alguma dúvida, vais achar "interessante" alguns contra-argumentos.

Comment: `<div>1 + 1</div><div><strong>2</strong></div>` Feito =P

Comment: @MarceloBoni acertouuuuuu

Answer (score 18):

HTML, *Linguagem de Marcação de Hipertexto*, não chega a ser uma linguagem de programação, é apenas  um padrão de marcação, como dito na resposta do @Maniero, o HTML não é executável, ela necessita de um interpretador para ler suas marcações, e o interpretador é o próprio navegador.

XML, JSON, SVG, CSS, RSS entre outros são padrões como o HTML.... eles servem para propósitos diferentes e/ou semelhantes, dependendo da sua necessidade, não chegam a ser uma linguagem de programação, mas servem como padrões de leitura.....novamente dou um enfoque nessa parte: não são linguagem compiladas, e sim "interpretadas", os navegadores as interpretam, e mostram o resultado na tela.

Claro que a idéia de *compilação* e *interpretação* é MUITO parecida....
Mas algo que pode deixar mas claro essa visão vamos usar como exemplo o JAVA e o XML

Ao criar um sistema em JAVA, e compilá-lo, ele executara igualmente em qualquer computador que possua a JVM (*Java Virtual Machine*)

Já no caso do XML, dependendo da sua implementação, pode servir pra N propósitos e com N diferenças.

Nem precisamos ir muito longe, uma página HTML mesmo, dependendo do navegador que você utilizar(Chrome, Opera, Safari, Firefox e o Monstrinho azul da Microsoft, mais conhecido como IE), ele irá interpretar as marcações da página de um forma diferente que um outro.

Comment: Compreendi o seu ponto, e se achar que devemos fechar use mesmo a opção pra fechar amigo @Marcelo Bonifazio. Fiquei com uma dúvida no que disse, todas as linguagens interpretadas não são de programação amigo?

Comment: A parte que responde a pergunta está certa mas essa comparação com interpretação e com o Java está um pouco *misleading* (enganosa?).

Answer (score -5):

Hum ... apesar de ressuscitar uma questão antiga ser uma atitude duvidosa, vou responder e discordar da corrente: sim, HTML é linguagem de programação. Vou simplesmente [copiar trechos de uma resposta que já dei no Quora](https://pt.quora.com/HTML-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/answer/Anderson-Torres-4):

---

Esta é uma questão de definição.

Uma linguagem de programação é uma linguagem formal - um vocabulário mais regras - usadas para um dispositivo computacional realizar uma tarefa dada.

Neste sentido, afirma David A. Schmidt em seu livro ["Denotational Semantics"](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~bec/courses/csci5535/reading/densem.pdf):

> Any notation for giving instructions is a programming language. Arithmetic notation is a programming language; so is Pascal. The input data format for an applications program is also a programming language. The person who uses an applications program thinks of its input commands as a language, just like the program’s implementor thought of Pascal when he used it to implement the applications program. The person who wrote the Pascal compiler had a similar view about the language used for coding the compiler. This series of languages and viewpoints terminates at the physical machine, where code is converted into action.

Em ptBR:

> Qualquer notação para fornecer instruções é uma linguagem de programação. Notação aritmética é uma linguagem de programação; assim o é Pascal. O formato de dados de entrada para uma aplicativo também é uma linguagem de programação. A pessoa que usa um aplicativo pensa na entrada de comandos como uma linguagem, bem como o implementador do programa pensava de Pascal quando o usava para implementar o aplicativo. A pessoa que escreveu o compilador Pascal tinha uma visão semelhante sobre a linguagem usada para implementar o compilador. Esta série de pontos de vista e linguagens encerra na máquina física, onde o código é convertido em ação.

Esta descrição certamente engloba o HTML - com destaque para *"O formato de dados de entrada para uma aplicativo também é uma linguagem de programação"*.

Por outro lado, há alguns problemas em não se considerar HTML uma linguagem de programação. Primeiramente, um pouco de teoria.

Em Teoria da Computação, normalmente aprendem-se três formalismos (entre tantos outros): o autômato finito, o autômato de pilha e a máquina de Turing. Todos os três formalismos são "programáveis".

Por exemplo, é possível construir um autômato finito que verifique se a palavra "HTML" aparece em um texto dado. E esta é, certamente, uma tarefa computacional, e eu não preciso de um imenso poder de computação (no sentido de possibilidade teórica, não no de desempenho) para resolvê-la.

Como mais um exemplo, é possível construir um autômato de pilha que verifique se um determinado texto está com os parênteses balanceados. Esta é uma tarefa computacional, e não é necessário um poder computacional imenso para resolvê-lo. Um pouco mais que um autômato finito, certamente, mas não uma máquina de Turing completa.

E como último exemplo, é necessária uma máquina de Turing para computar se todas as letras de um determinado texto aparecem em quantidades iguais.

Intuitivamente, todas essas tarefas são computacionais, é algo difícil de negar. Então, é muito estranho negar que os "computadores formais" que as executam não sejam computadores, muito menos que não sejam "programáveis" em algum sentido. Se somente a máquina de Turing é uma linguagem de programação, por que as outras duas não são?

Com isto, fica estabelecido que máquinas programáveis não se restringem às de Turing, e por conseguinte linguagens de programação não se restringem às Turing-completas.

Com isto, pergunta-se: Por que muitas pessoas dizem que HTML não é linguagem de programação?

Eu diria que por pura ignorância (aqui, sinônimo de desconhecimento) ou por quebra de expectativa. Há algumas objeções comuns

Por exemplo, normalmente pensa-se mais em linguagens de programação com alguma forma de interatividade, como o `getchar()`. Mas esta é uma ideia restrita. Existem muitos programas complexos sem muitos pontos de interação com o usuário. Drivers de placa de vídeo e BIOSes de computadores, por exemplo.

Outras vezes, alega-se "mas HTML é uma linguagem de formatação". Mas isso é uma falsa dicotomia. Afinal, o HTML é uma linguagem de formatação, portanto ela é uma linguagem (vocabulário mais regras) usada para um dispositivo (navegador de internet) realizar uma tarefa (a saber, formatação). Portanto, é uma linguagem de programação *e* formatação, ambos ao mesmo tempo.

Outros podem afirmar "Mas ela não é Turing-completa" (ou alo equivalente "faz um sistema operacional em HTML"). Isso também não é muito correto. Há linguagens de domínio específico (Domain Specific Languages) que não se preocupam sequer em ser Turing-completas, como ANSI SQL92, Coq e Agda.

Sobre Coq, podemos até recorrer ao [sítio oficial](https://coq.inria.fr/about-coq):

> Coq implements a program specification and mathematical higher-level language called Gallina that is based on an expressive formal language called the Calculus of Inductive Constructions that itself combines both a higher-order logic and a richly-typed functional programming language.

Finalmente, para lançar por terra essa falsa dicotomia: a *linguagem de formatação* TeX é reconhecidamente Turing-completa.

---

Comment: Logo CSS e XML são, também, linguagens de programação? Aliás, não é uma atitude duvidosa discordar, não., desde que deixe claro todas as discordâncias e apresente contra-argumentos :D (não entrando no mérito se fez isso ou não, apenas esclarecendo)

Comment: Também posso passar um arquivo JSON para um dispositivo para que o mesmo realize tarefas. Neste caso o JSON seria uma linguagem de programação?

Comment: Na realidade existe uma esolang baseada em JSON - a AJSOne: https://esolangs.org/wiki/Ajsone

Comment: Autômatos finitos e de pilha não são programáveis. Eles são programas propriamente ditos. Uma máquina de Turing também é um programa, só que um programa que aceita outro programa para fazer uma computação.

Comment: Depende do que você quer dizer. De maneira genérica, um autômato finito é uma descrição de uma máquina. Esta descrição é um programa, mas não é um programa que seria executado por um autômato finito.

Neste sentido, uma implementação particular do formalismo não é programável, mas o formalismo em si o é. O próprio programa [JFLAP](https://www.jflap.org) faz isso.