# Usar nome da planilha extraído de uma célula

Tags: microsoft-excel

Estou criando uma pasta de trabalho no excel que servirá de modelo para muitas outras que serão geradas através dela.

Esta pasta de trabalho modelo possui 5 planilhas, e uma dela poderá ser replicada diversas vezes com vários nomes diferentes como: Financeiro, Faturamento, Fiscal, etc, dependendo da necessidade de cada projeto.

Uma das minhas planilhas contém uma referência a dados que aparecem nestas planilhas novas através de uma fórmula. Abaixo vou dar o exemplo de como está a minha planilha:

```
Títulos:
Nome 001
Nome 002
Nome 003

Tabela:
Financeiro
Faturamento
Tecnologia

Pontos:
115
168
985
```

A coluna de pontos hoje possui uma fórmula onde eu insiro, manualmente, o nome da planilha que ele precisa buscar, por exemplo: Financeiro!A1:C50. O que eu gostaria é poder buscar na planilha que leva o mesmo nome da coluna, assim ficaria dinâmico.

OBS: O número de linhas para cada projeto nesta planilha de resumo também é variável, por isso preciso deixar a fórmula pegando na coluna de Tabela para poder calcular.

Abaixo o código da coluna pontos seguindo:

```
=SE(ÉERROS(ÍNDICE(Modelo!$D$3:$BA$3;1;CORRESP($C5;Modelo!$D$3:$BA$3;0) + 2));"";ÍNDICE(Modelo!$D$3:$BA$3;1;CORRESP($C5;Modelo!$D$3:$BA$3;0) + 2))
```

Comment: `[sobre a suspensão da pergunta]` Fórmulas de Excel está com pontuação de +8/-3 em [Quais assuntos devem fazer parte do nosso foco (on-topic)?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1436/201)

Comment: Afinal [o Excel pode ser considerado uma linguagem de programação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35547/html-%c3%a9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%c3%a7%c3%a3o#comment71719_35548) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finalmente achei a solução graças a um amigo que me apontou um [**link**](http://forum.baboo.com.br/index.php?/topic/637258-usando-valor-dentro-de-c%C3%A9lula-como-refer%C3%AAncia-a-planilha-em-f%C3%B3rmula/) que o ajudou a solucionar o mesmo problema dele. Vou colar o texto da referência aqui apenas adaptando a minha pergunta para contextualizar:

> Use a seguinte função:
>
> 1) **INDIRETO(texto_ref; [a1])** - A função indireto, pega textos que
>   representam um endereço de célula, retornando o valor desta célula.
>
> **[a1]**: não se preocupe com esse parâmetro, não é necessário.
>
> Então se você escrever em uma célula qualquer:
>
> **=INDIRETO(B1)**
>
> Supondo que em B1 estivesse escrito Financeiro!A2, na verdade
>   retornaria o valor da célula A2 da planilha 'Financeiro'. Já, se você
>   escrever:
>
> **=INDIRETO("B1")**
>
> A função reconhece B1 como um texto que retorna uma célula, retornando
>   o valor de célula B1. Isso é ótimo para o que você quer, em vez de por
>   B1 a gente vai escrever algo que soluciona o seu problema.
>
> Sabendo que escrever o símbolo & junta dois textos a gente pode agora
>   juntar B1, onde está escrito Financeiro, com um texto escrito !A2,
>   dessa forma escrevendo em uma célula qualquer: 
>   =B1&"!A2". Isso vai retornar o texto Financeiro!A2. Escrevendo dentro da função INDIRETO() vai retornar o que você quer, basta escrever:
>   **=INDIRETO(B1&"!A2")**.

No meu caso a minha fórmula fica:

```
=SE(ÉERROS(ÍNDICE(INDIRETO(D5&"!$D$3:$BA$3");1;CORRESP($C5;INDIRETO(D5&"!$D$3:$BA$3");0) + 2));"";ÍNDICE(INDIRETO(D5&"!$D$3:$BA$3");1;CORRESP($C5;INDIRETO(D5&"!$D$3:$BA$3");0) + 2))
```