# O que é o Vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, terminologia

Já encontrei em vários lugares este termo, "Vanilla JS". Ele parece ser citado como um *framework*, mas nos códigos onde ele é citado e no próprio site o código apresentado é puro JavaScript.

Comment: Vanilla JS, é uma piada, então utiliza apenas javascript puro, [aqui tem um comparativo de velocidade](http://vanilla-js.com/), mostrando as versão javascript de alguns códigos de framework populares. Hehe. (É algo tipo: "Não utilizo bibliotecas").

Comment: A brincadeira é mais ou menos [assim](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif)

Comment: Vem do inglês. Eles chamam de _vanilla_ (baunilha) qualquer coisa que seja sem nada extra, ordinário, regular. Por exemplo, sexo papai-mamãe é "baunilha".

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Você viu certo, é JavaScript puro. Talvez a forma apresentada para parecer como um *framework* seja proposital como forma de piada já que há crítica sobre a proliferação de *frameworks* que em geral pouco agregam de fato.

Provavelmente o *site* que você viu é [esse](http://vanilla-js.com/). O objetivo dele é divulgar de forma jocosa o uso de JavaScript puro em detrimento aos *frameworks* já que estes últimos não permitem fazer nada novo, no máximo, e isto muitas vezes pode ser questionado, de forma mais fácil.

Não nego que existem algumas vantagens no uso de alguns destes *frameworks* mas eles também trazem desvantagens que muitas pessoas ignoram tais como o aumento no consumo de recursos e a dificuldade de enxergar o que realmente está acontecendo.

Você [pode ler mais a respeito no Google](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?q=why%20not%20use%20frameworks) (a lista é muito grande para listar um a um).

Vou aproveitar a oportunidade para esclarecer uma confusão muito comum:

## jQuery NÃO é uma linguagem de programação

jQuery é apenas uma biblioteca, ou se preferir, [chame-o de *framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101). Mas, por favor, não chame ele de linguagem de programação. O mesmo vale para outras bibliotecas feitas para auxiliarem o uso do JavaScript. O mesmo vale para ASP.Net ser chamada de linguagem, quando é apenas uma tecnologia.

jQuery depende de outra linguagem de programação diretamente. Ou seja, sem a sintaxe do JavaScript, não é possível fazer nada com jQuery. Não é uma questão que o jQuery exista por si só e depois é convertido para JS, [como ocorre com outras linguagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101).

O objetivo desta biblioteca é facilitar escrever alguns padrões, encurtar o código, compatibilizar o uso entre os diversos navegadores e fornecer algumas operações comumente necessárias quando se está escrevendo código JavaScript, normalmente usando uma uma [sintaxe Fluente](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). Note que usando jQuery você ainda escreve código JS, mesmo que não pareça.

jQuery aumenta o [nível de abstração](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29).

jQuery não possui variáveis, elas são usadas porque o JS as possui. Embora a biblioteca tenha função que evitam o uso de controle de fluxo em muitas situações, ela não tem nenhum controle, nem mesmo a chamada de funções é dela própria. Toda semântica de programação em linguagens de programação, ou seja, em linguagens que são [*turing complete*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) só está presente na parte fornecida pelo JS.

Então você não programa EM jQuery, você programa em JavaScript COM jQuery. Assim como você [não programa em HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101).

## [Pode ser que você não precise de jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Segue documentação do Vanilla JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript. kkkk

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, `UP` no seu comentário, pela bela referência a documentação. kkkkk. E não se esqueçam de incluir a biblioteca `vanilla.js`, senão não funciona. kkkkkk

Comment: É o principal @Fernando!! Aconselho 'checkar' todas as funcionalidades antes de baixar, para ter o pacote completo.

Comment: @Fernando a  maioria dos navegadores modernos não precisam mais incluir mais o vanilla.js podendo ser usado nativamente 

Answer (score 46):

É JavaScript puro mesmo. Em inglês existe essa expressão "vanilla [something]" para se referir à variante mais comum, mais simples ou mais pura de algo - talvez porque "baunilha" seja o sabor mais básico de quitutes como biscoitos, sorvete, etc.

Answer (score 22):

Como já disseram é apenas uma piada. O Vanilla foi uma forma inteligente de fazer uma critica a uso indiscriminado de frameworks ou bibliotecas, quando você deveria apenas usar o javascript puro.

Aqui outra brincadeira como exemplo:
[**needsmorejquery**](http://needsmorejquery.com)

Answer (score 19):

Não necessariamente era piada. O termo "Vanilla _______" em si é algo sério e usado em diversas áreas. Vide: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software

> is called vanilla when not customized from its original form, meaning
>   that it is used without any customizations or updates applied to
>   it.[...] The term comes from the traditional standard flavor of ice cream, vanilla flavor.

Traduzindo:

> é chamado de vanilla (baunilha) quando é algo não customizado da sua forma original, significando que é usado sem customização ou updates aplicados à ele. [...] O termo vem do tradicional sabor padrão de sorvete, baunilha.

Outro exemplo da utilização: `Building and installing a vanilla Linux kernel on Ubuntu`, ou seja um kernel de linux puro, sem customizações.

Comment: Vale a tradução do trecho, já que é o que explica o que é Vanilla ***.

Comment: @cantoni traduzido. Obrigado pelo toque ;-)

Answer (score 13):

JavaScript mais puro que esse não tem muitos por ai não, no [site](http://vanilla-js.com/) quando se faz o download o que vem é um arquivo chamado vanilla.js sem nada.

Answer (score -6):

Como já foi dito acima por vários colegas, o VanillaJS é apenas uma forma sarcástica de se referir a JS puro. Então **VanillaJS** é o mesmo que **JavaScript Puro**.

Comment: Se já foi dito, não entendi qual foi o propósito da resposta. Tem alguma informação a mais?

Comment: Depois de quase 5 anos que a pergunta foi feita achei que apareceria algo novo, mas parece que não...