# get_meta_tags não funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html

Fiz um *script* em JavaScript e PHP, no qual preciso pegar a primeira *keyword* (meta keyword) da página `document.referrer`.

Não adianta usar o `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` que não funciona no meu caso, porque a página que está sendo executada está dentro de um *iframe*, dessa maneira, não funciona.

Portanto, fiz o seguinte código:

```php
// O script abaixo, pega a URL presente do navegador, até aqui funciona perfeito, ele pega certinho o que preciso
<script>
function getParentUrl() {
    var isInIframe = (parent !== window),
        parentUrl = null;

    if (isInIframe) {
        parentUrl = document.referrer;
    }

    return parentUrl;
}
var referencia = getParentUrl();
</script>
<?php
// a variavel abaixo, pega o valor do javascript, e recebe certinho a variavel
$referenciaphp = "<script>document.write(referencia)</script>";
echo $referenciaphp;

//abaixo está o problema
$tags = get_meta_tags($referenciaphp);

echo $tags;
$palavras=$tags['keywords'];
$individual=explode(",", $palavras);
echo $individual[0];
?>
```

O problema é no momento de acionar a `get_meta_tags`, se eu dar um `echo` na variável, ele mostra a URL certinha, mas não funciona no momento de pegar as tags, não sei se é o tipo de variável que tem que mudar, ou algo pelo estilo.

Eu testei trocando para `$referenciaphp = "http://www.uol.com.br/";`, e funciona perfeitamente o script.

O problema é apenas quando se usa uma variável vinda do JavaScript, não sei se tem que converter a variável ou algo do tipo.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de você estar vendo a variável no mesmo arquivo, quando é executado a parte do PHP e a parte do JavaScript não estão juntas, o PHP executa no servidor e o JS executa no navegador. Elas não conversam diretamente, seu código precisa prover uma forma de comunicação entre eles.

Tem outras formas de fazer isto inclusive de um jeito melhor (não vou entrar nos outros problemas do seu código) mas o mais próximo do que você está fazendo é enviar a variável para o PHP via AJAX.

```
<script>
function getParentUrl() {
    var isInIframe = (parent !== window),
        parentUrl = null;

    if (isInIframe) {
        parentUrl = document.referrer;
    }

    return parentUrl;
}
var referencia = getParentUrl();

(function() {
  var httpRequest;
  document.getElementById("ajaxButton").onclick = function() {
          makeRequest('suapagina.php?referencia=' + referencia); };

  function makeRequest(url) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
      try {
        httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } 
      catch (e) {
        try {
          httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } 
        catch (e) {}
      }
    }

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
})();
</script>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/GetMetatags.js).

Este código executará quando houver um *click* no botão de nome `ajaxButton`. Mas é possível alterar para ocorrer na carga da página:

```
window.onload = function() { makeRequest('suapagina.php?referencia=' + referencia); };
```

Algumas pessoas preferem usar [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) para facilitar. Outros preferem deste jeito mesmo, o [Vanilla JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101).

E note que este código é uma receita básica, ele não foi criado pensando nas suas necessidades específicas, ele precisa ser adaptado.

No PHP `suapagina.php` você receberá a variável assim:

```
<?php
$referenciaphp = $GET["referecia"];
$tags = get_meta_tags($referenciaphp);
$palavras=$tags['keywords'];
$individual=explode(",", $palavras);
echo $individual[0];
?>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/GetMetatags.php).

[Referência do AJAX na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).