# jQuery influi na "performance" da aplicação?

Tags: javascript, jquery, desempenho

Eu, pessoalmente, amo e utilizo a biblioteca jQuery.

Essa biblioteca influencia na "performance" da aplicação?

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 10):

Sim.

O jQuery é uma biblioteca relativamente pesada. Sempre que usares seletores jQuery vais estar a correr muitas funções que podem pesar no desempenho da aplicação.

Por exemplo se quiseres saber o `id` de um elemento podes fazer em jQuery `$(el).attr('id')` mas podes obter o mesmo usando JavaScript puro com `el.id`, a diferença de performance é grande: http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-this-attr-id-vs-this-id/12

Claro que é útil usar jQuery, ou MooTools, ou outra biblioteca. Mas á medida que o JavaScript evolui fica mais fácil de fazer o que se precisa com código nativo (ou CSS) e sem perdas de performance.

Comment: Esse jsperfom apenas do seletor tbm é legal pra comparar https://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/22

Answer (score 6):

Sem dúvida influencia. É uma camada extra que irá executar coisas extras que nem sempre são necessárias se você fizer diretamente em [Vanilla JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101).

Além disto esconder as coisas pode ajudar de um lado e pode complicar de outro. Nem sempre é fácil perceber as ineficiências do que se está fazendo quando usa uma biblioteca. É verdade que se o programador não entende as ineficiências da linguagem, da biblioteca padrão ou mesmo do computador em geral, não faz diferença.

A culpa pode ser diretamente do jQuery, pode ser do programador usando ele mas também pode ser dos *plugins* para jQuery que nem sempre são bem escritos. Mas mesmo os que são ainda terão perdas por serem uma cama extra.

Algumas pessoas colocam o custo de carregar a biblioteca como outra forma de piorar a performance. Claro que carregar na memória e preparar todo ambiente tem um custo mas este custo que reclamam é o da carga do *download* via internet. Isto faz sentido e eventualmente pode acontecer e degradar a carga da sua página significativamente. Mas se a página usa a técnica de carregar o arquivo minimificado de um CDN que todo mundo usa, como o [oficial](http://jquery.com/download/) ou da [Google](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) que muitas pessoas usam, usará do cache e não precisará fazer *download*.

Não estou dizendo que esta perda inviabilize seu uso, claro, se fosse assim haveria muitas pessoas cometendo um erro gravíssimo. O que eu critico mais é quando há abuse. Algumas pessoas transformaram uma biblioteca em linguagem. Aí a pessoa não consegue fazer mais nada em JS mesmo quando claramente o JS é melhor em velocidade, legibilidade, etc. O problema se torna maior quando o programador usa para digitar menos - e não tornar o código mais conciso, o que é uma virtude.

Mas para a maioria das tarefas essa perda não chega afetar significativamente.

[Algumas comparações](http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-javascript-performance-comparison/22).

Qual você acha mais rápido? Um [`for each`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in) simples ou o [`each`](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=2.0.3&fn=jQuery.each) (veja o código do *link*) do jQuery que além do `for each` faz um monte de coisa?

Answer (score 2):

Sim influência, contudo em grande parte dos casos a diferença é irrelevante no resultado final pois os motores de JavaScript nos navegadores atuais são extremamente eficientes e a jQuery já é bem otimizada.

Você vai ver por aí várias pessoas mostrando como seletores ou métodos nativos do browser tipo `document.getElementById` são incrivelmente mais rápidos que equivalentes jQuery (tipo `$('')` ou `$(...).prop('id')`) e é verdade, o método wrapper é bem menos eficiente, porém ainda assim você vai ter que se esforçar *bastante* para isso refletir negativamente no desempenho **perceptível** da sua aplicação. Geralmente problemas de performance vem de código ruim e não do [overhead](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overhead_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) causado pela biblioteca sendo usada, um excelente exemplo sendo [este post do John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/) que fala sobre um caso onde o twitter estava travando quando o usuário fazia scroll na página, resultado de uma função que fazia queries na DOM a cada scroll feito (o que é muito, muito ruim).

Não é parte da sua pergunta (ela já foi respondida no "Sim", a primeira palavra desta resposta ;)) mas vou deixar o conselho de que a não ser que você esteja fazendo um app que precise de um nível muito grande de otimização se atenha a usar jQuery (ou outra lib equivalente) já que ela te tira várias dores de cabeça existentes ao escrever raw javascript (ela te da uma API mais simples, código mais legível, uniformização de comportamento entre browsers, etc).