# Como executar código apenas no primeiro clique?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma lista de botões (`<li>`):

```
<li id="1">link 1</li>
<li id="2">link 2</li>
<li id="3">link 3</li>
<li id="4">link 4</li>
<li id="5">link 5</li>
```

Quando o usuário clica em um *link* ele executa um *Ajax* e faz uma requisição em um arquivo PHP, quando clica em outro, ele faz a mesma requisição e a assim sucessivamente.

Gostaria de saber como faço para quando o usuário clicar no *link* e apenas no primeiro clique fazer a requisição e se ele clicar de novo não fazer mais a requisição.

<sup>PS.: Quando ele clica em qualquer um dos *links*, ele executa o evento `html()` que guarda os resultados em uma div que fica logo ao lado das `<li>`</sup>

Comment: Como você está fazendo atualmente? Existem muitas maneiras, a questão é escolher uma que se encaixe bem no resto do seu código...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma maneira de se fazer isso é através de [`$.one`](https://api.jquery.com/one/). Ele coloca um tratador de eventos no conjunto de elementos selecionados, de forma que o tratador somente será chamado uma única vez para cada elemento do conjunto. Exemplo:

```js
$("li").one("click", function() { 
    alert("click"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="1">link 1</li>
<li id="2">link 2</li>
<li id="3">link 3</li>
<li id="4">link 4</li>
<li id="5">link 5</li>
```

Note que se fizer isso não há uma maneira simples de "religar" o tratador de eventos caso você precise fazê-lo por algum motivo (por exemplo, se a chamada ajax falhar, e você quiser que um elemento individual da lista possa ser clicado de novo). O máximo que você pode fazer é recolocar o tratador no futuro (pois o que o `one` faz é remover o tratador após ele ser chamado).

Answer (score 6):

Para além da maneira [que o mgibsonbr já indicou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58266/129), que permite fazer *click* só uma vez, podes precisar de outra variante caso precises guardar no DOM a informação se já foi clicado (para além de não permitir mais que 1 vez).

Podes fazer isso assim, guardando um `data-clicado` no elemento:

```
$('li').on('click', function (e) {

    var clicado = $(this).data('clicado');

    // se "clicado" tiver valor o click não é mais seguido
    if (clicado) return e.preventDefault();

    // aqui juntas um timestamp ao elemento para saberes que foi clicado e quando
    $(this).data('clicado', new Date().getTime()); 

    $.ajax... // o teu código de ajax aqui...
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Deixando uma solução em [Vanilla JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/223) para anexar um evento de `click` em cada `<li/>` presente na `<ul/>` especificada onde o mesmo só dispara uma vez.

## Exemplo

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("minhaLista");

var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  items[i].addEventListener("click", handler);
}


function handler(e) {

  e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);

  alert("Teste, uma vez por clique em cada LI!");
}
```

```html
<ul id="minhaLista">
  <li id="1">link 1</li>
  <li id="2">link 2</li>
  <li id="3">link 3</li>
  <li id="4">link 4</li>
  <li id="5">link 5</li>
</ul>
```

## Explicação

- Identificar a `<ul/>`:

  ```
  var ul = document.getElementById("minhaLista");
  ```
- Apanhar as `<li/>` dentro da `<ul/>`:

  ```
  var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  ```
- Por cada `<li/>`, anexar evento `click`:

  ```
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      items[i].addEventListener("click", handler);
  }
  ```
- Função chamada no evento anexado que remove o próprio evento após primeiro uso:

  ```
  function handler(e) {

      // remover evento para não voltar a executar
      e.target.removeEventListener(e.type, arguments.callee);

      // código a executar aqui...
      alert("Teste, uma vez por clique em cada LI!");
  }
  ```

Comment: +1 isso é basicamente o que o `jQuery.one` faz, mas sem jQuery - bom pros casos em que o jQuery (e todos os seus KB) não é realmente necessário.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Bem verdade! E parece relevante ir deixando soluções sem recurso a jQuery sempre que a oportunidade surge, [tag:javascript], uma vez que Vanilla JS está a cair no esquecimento...