# Detectar se o evento foi disparado pelo usuário ou via script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando detectar se o evento (`click`) foi disparado pelo usuário ou pelo método `trigger` do jQuery.

Analisando o parâmetro `event` encontrei duas propriedades que eu poderia utilizar para esta verificação: quando o evento é disparado via `trigger` o objeto possui a propriedade `isTrigger` e quando o usuário aciona o evento, o objeto possui a propriedade `originalEvent`.

A dúvida é, estas soluções são padrões da api do jQuery ou podem ser alteradas em futuras versões? Qual delas devo utilizar?

Comment: Qual é o evento que queres usar?

Comment: Normalmente o evento que precisa desta verificação é o `click`.

Comment: Procurei na documentação do jQuery e não encontrei referido especificamente nada que possa responder com certeza :^) És tu que geras esses clics sintéticos?

Comment: @Sergio Sim, eu que aciono os eventos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Vanilla JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/223)

Podemos observar as propriedades do objeto `event` associado ao mesmo, particularmente as que registam as coordenadas do clique.

Se o clique foi disparado programaticamente, vão estar a zero.

Se o clique foi realizado pelo utilizador, vão conter as coordenadas da localização onde ocorreu o clique em relação à tela.

Para o efeito, fazemos uso das propriedades [`clientX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX) e [`clientY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientY):

```
if (e.screenX && e.screenX!=0 && e.screenY && e.screenY!=0) {
    // clique real, realizado por um humano ou um robô que usa o rato
}
else {
    // clique programático
}
```

### Exemplo

```js
var myButton = document.getElementById("meuBotao");

// se receber clique, debitar para a consola o objeto `event`
myButton.onclick = function(event) {
  console.log(event);
}

// disparar o clique manual (vai ser o primeiro a aparecer na consola)
myButton.click();
```

```html
<button id="meuBotao">clica-me</button>
```

## jQuery `event.isTrigger`

Com jQuery, a partir da versão 1.7, a *framework* do mesmo lida com este problema e define uma propriedade no objeto do evento de clique para sinalizar se o clique foi realizado programaticamente:

```
// Linha #4521 do ficheiro http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.js
event.isTrigger = onlyHandlers ? 2 : 3;
```

Não existe documentação oficinal para esta propriedade, e no [fórum do jQuery](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/event-istrigger) ainda não existe uma resposta definitiva para o assunto.

Se observarmos o código fonte da versão 1.7 do jQuery onde vimos esta propriedade pela primeira vez:

```
// Linha #3141 do ficheiro http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js
event.isTrigger = true;
```

Dá para constatar que existem diferenças, dando-nos a entender que a propriedade é mais para controlo interno da própria *framework* e pode mudar em futuras versões.

Em suma, pode-se concluir que não devemos considerar esta propriedade como viável para o objetivo de detetar a origem do clique sendo preferível uma solução em Vanilla JavaScript.

## jQuery `event.originalEvent`

De qualquer forma, temos a o objeto `event.originalEvent` que estará definido apenas se o clique ocorreu por um rato ou touch:

```
$('button').on('click', function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent === undefined) {
        // clique programatico
    }
    else {
        // clique rato ou touch
    }
});
```

Este objeto contém o que o objeto `event` contém, e é anexado apenas se o evento foi despoletado por rato ou *touch*.

Digamos que é uma cópia do evento original porque a *framework* precisa de manipular inúmeras propriedades e assim pode fazê-lo sem perturbar o normal funcionamento dos objetos e propriedades a que estamos habituados em JavaScript:

> Alguns eventos podem ter propriedades específicas para eles. Essas podem ser acessadas como propriedades do objeto `event.originalEvent`.

<sup>Citação presente na documentação para [`Event Object`](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)</sup>

Como este objeto está documentado, já se aconselha o seu uso dado termos alguma garantia de que não vai mudar de forma repentina e sem aviso ou portabilidade.

Answer (score 1):

`isTrigger` é atribuíto para `true` no corpo do método `trigger()`, então é garantido que esta propriedade sempre existirá e sempre será `true` caso o evento tenha sido disparado via `trigger()`.
Testar `if (event.isTrigger) { ... }` é o suficiente e sempre resultará no comportamento esperado - separar eventos do usuário dos eventos do programador.

OBS: `originalEvent` sempre aponta para o evento nativo criado pelo navegador, o que sugere que essa propriedade sempre será `undefined` quando o evento for disparado via `trigger()` - mas a documentação não garante esse comportamento.