# jQuery ainda é "necessário"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho me questionado recentemente sobre a real necessidade de ainda se utilizar jQuery em novos projetos para a Web. Sei que ele era, até pouco tempo atrás, o melhor meio (e para muitos casos o único) de se manipular elementos Html e fazer requisições Web sem se preocupar com as diferenças entre navegadores e sem ter que escrever milhares de linhas de código para realizar tarefas simples.

As seguintes funcionalidades hoje são facilmente obtidas com Javascript nativos dos navegadores:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tirei a ideia das funcionalidades [daqui](http://blog.romanliutikov.com/post/63383858003/how-to-forget-about-jquery-and-start-using-native).

Eu sei que a sintaxe do jQuery é na maioria das vezes, mais clara e compacta. Mas a pergunta é: **o jQuery ainda é "necessário"**?

Nota: Coloco o necessário entre aspas, pois sei que não existe necessidade no sentido estrito da palavra.

Comment: jQuery não é nem nunca foi necessário. Ele nunca passou de uma conveniência.

Comment: Alterei o título e coloquei o necessário entre aspas. Sei que nunca foi necessário, mas tenho a impressão de que hoje em dia é muito mais fácil desconsiderá-lo em novas implementações. Esperava encontrar argumentos que digam o contrário...

Comment: Estou reabrindo a pergunta por entender que a dúvida é sobre a compatibilidade entre os browsers modernos.

Comment: Por isso e para conseguir argumentos técnicos, não baseados em opinião, para se adotar jQuery em novos projetos.

Comment: Quanto ao IE, classList só funciona no IE10 em diante e parcialmente! http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist Se você se preocupa com navegadores mais antigos, jQuery é excelente para cuidar das diferenças crossbrowser

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Por que jQuery?

O jQuery foi lançado em 2006, em uma época em que as APIs mais utilizadas do JavaScript não eram 100% compatíveis entre os navegadores. Essa camada de compatibilidade do jQuery acabou com que [**90% dos top 1.000.000** de sites do mundo](https://trends.builtwith.com/javascript/jQuery) utilizassem essa biblioteca. É um número muito expressivo.

[image]
 <sup>*Dados de uso do jQuery entre os sites mais visitados do mundo.*</sup>

O grande ponto do jQuery não é a sintaxe compacta, e sim a compatibilidade entre os navegadores. Fazendo uma análise crítica, a sintaxe do jQuery não é nada clara: você não consegue dizer o que `$("#abc")` está fazendo.

## JavaScript puro

Mas o JavaScript evoluiu, se consolidou, e ficou maduro com o passar dos anos. Tem-se uma especificação ([ECMA-262](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)) bem definida, e hoje, seguida pelos navegadores. Antes isso era sonho.

Hoje, fazer uma requisição HTTP com JavaScript puro é muito simples:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', '/my/url', true);
request.send(data);
```

Outra facilidade do jQuery são as animações, porém, em 2019, isso é muito melhor [executado com CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp), por utilizar GPU e não CPU para algumas coisas.

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
   0% {opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

E o problema de compatibilidade entre os navegadores foi resolvido tanto pela maturação do linguagem e das especificações, mas também pelos compiladores, como o [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Ele transforma:

```
[1, 2, 3].map((n) => n ** 2)
```

em

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function (n) {
  return Math.pow(n, 2);
});
```

## jQuery ainda é necessário?

De fato, jQuery foi necessário, tal que 90% dos top 1.000.000 de sites do mundo utilizaram. Era inviável programar para cada engine de JavaScript de 2006. Mas hoje, existem alternativas melhores, mais performáticas, e mais elegantes para resolver o problema mais crítico: compatibilidade. [Talvez você não precise de jQuery.](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

> Verbosidade não é necessariamente ruim. E simplicidade não é necessariamente bom.

Comment: Minha questão era mesmo uma provocação. Há 4 anos atrás eu já não via muito sentindo em usar o jQuery, mas quis levantar essa questão porque via muita gente ainda defendendo seu uso ainda em 2015. Hoje ele ainda está por todo lado, mas não ouço mais falar de projetos começando com jQuery.

Comment: Resolvi responder ela pq hoje vi os resultados da Developer Survey 2019 do Stack Overflow. Lá diz que 50% dos desenvolvedores utilizam jQuery agora em 2019.

Answer (score 4):

> "As seguintes funcionalidades hoje são facilmente obtidas com Javascript nativos dos navegadores"

E sempre foram, como acha que o jQuery foi escrito? O jQuery **é** JavaScript, sua utilização é apenas para encurtar o código. Vindo dessa ideia, o jQuery cresceu e virou o que é hoje, se tornando uma das melhores bibliotecas JavaScript.

Se é necessário? Isso vai de opinião para opinião. Eu acho que isso depende **muito** do projeto. Caso você queira algo com excelente velocidade, use Vanilla JS. Agora se é algo padrão que não precisa de nada extremo, qual o motivo de não se usar o jQuery?

Você prefere usar [isso](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/animations-with-vanilla-js) ao invés disso?

```
$('.element').animate({
  top: 50px,
  left: 50px
});
```

Outro exemplo é a conveniência de se usar `$('elemento.classe')` para pegar um elemento do DOM ao invés de `document.querySelectorAll("elemento.class")`.

Comment: O ponto é que os navegadores evoluíram muito da época que surgiu o jQuery até hoje. O jQuery é JavaScript, mas se hoje é possível escrever as mesmas funcionalidades sem ele (quase todas) com a mesma quantidade de linhas de código, por que usá-lo? Não é possível fazer animações com CSS3 e ainda mais rápido? E quanto ao seletor, se o $ é tão importante, que tal: `var $ = function (el) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(el);
}`

Comment: @MarcusVinicius ele não se referiu ao `$`, é um exemplo, o que ele quer dizer é a proposta do jQuery: *escreva menos*, em outras palavras a ideia do jQuery é você já ter várias coisas com poucas linhas. Se você for escrever uma aplicação ajax, você terá que escrever bem mais. Agora se você quiser adicionar o ajax em uma função e o `document.querySelectorAll` em outra, tecnicamente você começou uma biblioteca e você teve que escreve-la do mesmo jeito :)

Answer (score 1):

É necessário: **NÃO**
Jquery para os objetivos apontados na imagem é quase desnecessária (apesar que acho bem melhor utilizar jquery para fazer requisições AJAX) porem* quando se deseja trabalhar com a interface gráfica (faze-la ficar mais bonita, responsiva) de seu portal será necessário a utilização de algum plugin ou framework (caso não queira fazer tudo manualmente) eles tem como pré-requisitos o uso do jquery. Alguns exemplos de frameworks que tem com pré-requisito o jquery: 
`JQuery UI`, `Twitter-Bootstrap` e o `Fondation`.

*É necessário a presença do JQuery mas não é obrigatório o uso de suas funções, mas como ela já esta presente e como dito na própria pergunta `sintaxe do jQuery é na maioria das vezes, mais clara e compacta` seu uso neste caso é recomendado.

Comment: O Bootstrap é realmente um bom argumento para se incluir o jQuery. Tenho usado bastante em meus últimos projetos e ajuda muito.

Comment: @MarcusVinicius eu posso dizer que sem o Bootstrap (primeiro framework de UI) eu nunca daria conta de construir um projeto web sozinho ou com poucos recursos financeiros.

Comment: Vou marcar sua resposta como aceita, já que ninguém mais interagiu e você me deu um ótimo argumento para continuar usando o jQuery: O Bootstrap e outros plugins que facilitam muito a vida de desenvolvedores e designers.