# Usar Jquery ainda é vantajoso atualmente?

Tags: javascript, jquery, front-end

Gostaria de saber se o uso do Jquery ainda é vantajoso no desenvolvimento de frond-end com os recursos com EcmaScript 6 e afins.

Comment: Apesar de ter 4 anos, dá uma lida nesta postagem: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/60974/8063

Answer (score 3):

Depende do contexto, em geral não, mas em sites estáticos que você queira adicionar uns plugins de animação até pode ser (não significa que sempre vale)

O ES6, ao meu ver, não tem nada relação alguma, o que torna o jQuery "deprecated" é o fato de ser desorganizado em relação a tantas outras opções, como Angular, React, Vue e até mesmo o AngularJS que já foi descontinuado

No jQuery você tem um monte de arquivos bagunçados com muita coisa misturada, não existe um padrão adotado por toda a comunidade, você faz de um jeito o próximo a mexer no código de outro, e assim vai formando uma bola de neve

O jQuery nasceu com a ideia de um atalho pra algumas coisas do JavaScript, apenas um facilitador, nada mais. Enquanto os outros que citei já nasceram pra ser usados de cenários de um CRUD simples até um dashboard complexo, já vieram com um guia de estilo para todos os usuários seguirem

Mas se você tá fazendo apenas um site de divulgação da empresa do tio que a única ação mais complexa será o envio de email, até pode ser usado, facilita o desenvolvimento se você o já conhece e você tem muitos plugins de animação para adicionar ao site. Mas deve sempre pensar que jQuery + plugins resulta em mais dependências ao projeto e mais tempo de carregamento

Basicamente, jQuery pode ser bom pra design, nada mais