# Atualização automática com Javascript

Tags: javascript, atualização, requisição

Tenho uma página de rádio e preciso que a capa da música atual mude automaticamente, atualizando-a de 5 em 5 segundos, pegando a imagem de um arquivo externo que chamo de **lista-musicas.php** que retorna a tag:

```html
<img src="url-da-imagem" />
```

Eu tentei usar este código na página principal:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function atualiza_dados(){
        document.getElementById("tocando-agora").load("_includes/lista-musicas.php");
    }
    window.setInterval("atualiza_dados()", 4000);
</script>

<body onload="atualiza_dados()">
    <div id="tocando-agora"></div>
</body>
```

Porém, a requisição não funciona e a tag `<img>` não é carregada...
Eu comecei a aprender javascript há 2 dias, porém estou querendo resolver isso e não consigo, alguém me pode ajudar?

Answer (score 4):

Estás a misturar JavaScript com a Framework jQuery. O método [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) de jQuery serve precisamente para o que pretendes, mas em ["Vanilla JS"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/223) as coisas funcionam de uma forma diferente.

## Com jQuery:

```
$( "#minhaId" ).load( "ficheiro.html" );
```

A tua função ficaria:

```
function atualiza_dados(){

  // ler conteúdo do ficheiro para dentro do elemento indicado
  $( "minhaId" ).load( "ficheiro.html" );

  // esperar 4 segundos e chamar
  setTimeout( atualiza_dados, 4000 );
}

// executar código quando o DOM estiver pronto
$(function(){

  atualiza_dados(); // primeira chamada
});
```

## Com JavaScript:

De forma rápida podemos carregar o HTML numa tag [`<object/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) definindo o seu conteúdo como [`text/html`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/html):

```
document.getElementById("minhaId").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="ficheiro.html" ></object>';
```

<sup>De notar que este método está a tornar-se obsoleto.</sup>

A tua função ficaria:

```
function atualiza_dados(){

  // inserir um objeto na página a apontar para o ficheiro
  document.getElementById("minhaId").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="ficheiro.html" ></object>';

  // esperar 4 segundos e chamar
  setTimeout( atualiza_dados, 4000 );
}

// executar código quando o DOM estiver pronto
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
  atualiza_dados(); // primeira chamada
}, false);
```

De forma elaborada e mais funcional deverias fazer uso de uma [`<iframe/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) para garantires que o HTML que vais carregar na página não vai interferir com a mesma.

A tua função poderia ficar da seguinte forma:

```
function atualiza_dados() {

   var con = document.getElementById('minhaId')
   ,   xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function (e) { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
     con.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
   }

 xhr.open("GET", "http://www.example.com/ficheiro.html", true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
 xhr.send();
}
```

---

## Mudar imagem

Se o teu objetivo é única e exclusivamente atualizar a imagem de capa, podes simplificar bastante o processo se o teu script no lado do servidor estiver a enviar apenas a imagem pretendida.

O teu código poderia ficar da seguinte forma:

```
function atualiza_dados() {

  // localizar a imagem
  var img = document.getElementById("imagem");

  // alterar a imagem com novo timestamp
  img.src = (img.src).split('?')[0] + '?' + new Date().getTime();

  // esperar 4 segundos e chamar novamente
  setTimeout(atualiza_dados, 4000);
}

// executar código quando o DOM estiver pronto
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // primeira chamada
  setTimeout(atualiza_dados, 4000);

}, false);
```

E o teu script em PHP:

```
<?php

// apanhar nova capa de forma XPTO aqui ...

// enviar imagem para navegador
$file = '../caminho/para/ficheiro.jpg';
$type = 'image/jpeg';
header('Content-Type:'.$type);
readfile($file);
?>
```

**Exemplo**

Neste exemplo, podes ver a imagem a mudar, particularmente o número contido nela.

```js
var contador = 1;

function atualiza_dados() {

  // localizar a imagem
  var img = document.getElementById("imagem");

  // alterar a imagem
  img.src = img.src.replace("Zuul+" + contador, "Zuul+" + (contador + 1));

  contador++;

  // esperar 4 segundos e chamar novamente
  setTimeout(atualiza_dados, 4000);
}

// executar código quando o DOM estiver pronto
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // primeira chamada
  setTimeout(atualiza_dados, 4000);

}, false);
```

```html
<img id="imagem" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=14&bg=333333&txtclr=ffffff&txt=Zuul+1&w=200&h=200" alt="BuBu" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Seria de certo modo desajeitado converter o método `.load()` do `JQuery` que você está tentando utilizar para o `javascript` puro.

Você pode converter sua necessidade para 100% `JQuery`. Experimente:

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

(...)

<div id="tocando-agora"></div>

(...)
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    setInterval(function()
    {
        $("#tocando-agora").load("_includes/lista-musicas.php");
    }, 4000);
});
```

**Demo**

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/kz2q8u7d/2/)