# Qual é a diferença entre AngularJS e Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Estou estudando javascript e estou vendo alguns frameworks que são bem famosos, ainda não escolhi nenhum, mas já li sobre alguns, daí fiquei com dúvida:

- Qual a diferença entre AngularJS e Angular 2?
- Será que posso aprender o Angular 2 sem conhecer o AngularJS?

Comment: Seria interessante você editar a pergunta, de forma que ela não fique opinativa, me parece interessante, mas precisa ser alterada para não ser fechada.

Comment: Eu aprendi Jquery sem saber "Javascript", louco, não ? Haha.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre pior que muita gente aqui que usa jQuery nem faz idéia do que é JS, inclusive nem imagina que o jQuery é dispensável em quase todas as situações. Isso é mais comum do que pode parecer.

Comment: Entendo que a pergunta é fora de escopo, pois em princípio é apenas versão mais nova, não se tratam de frameworks separados. Reproduzir o changelog ou comparar versões sem razão específica não me parece um problema de programação.

Comment: @Bacco Poderia recomendar o pessoal quando for passar respostas enviar na linguagem, ao invés de bibliotecas. Mas acho que esse assunto fica pro Meta.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre acho melhor até no chat, não sei se justifica isso pro meta. Só quis comentar pra vc notar que é bem comum isso, que não precisa achar estranho :)

Comment: Essa situação que o Bacco falou é abominável. A pessoa não tem ideia do que ele está usando, de como funciona, porque usa aquilo, e acha que programa. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101

Comment: Então cara, não precisa não aprender o angular para ir para o angular 2, existem algumas "correções" assim podemos chamar que foram feitas no 2, que o diferenciam bastante na hora de utilizar. Se quer uma dica, na hora que for aprender, utiliza o style-guide que o John Papa fez, são boas práticas na hora de utilizar e deixam o seu código mais limpo. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a2 O tutorial do angular 2, já está no site oficial, e é bem bom pra começar, da uma olhada lá. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

Comment: @bigown eu já acho essa situação ótima, se a pessoa não sabe programar e ainda sim consegue desenvolver, significa que os recursos disponíveis estão entregando uma facilidade incrível. É claro que isso tem seu lado negativo quando se trata de algo mais complexo, mas atendendo as necessidades básicas de um leigo, não vejo grandes problemas.

Comment: @Orion a pessoa desenvolver algo sem precisar de experiência é uma coisa bem legal, por isso eu acho que essas linguagens de menor calibre, como PHP, Lua, tem seu papel e utilidade. O problema começa quando o cara se dá por satisfeito e se intitula programador com isso, e sai vendendo um conhecimento que não domina. O problema é basicamente esse. Sou extremamente a favor de que o máximo de pessoas tenha acesso a programação. Mas abomino quem cria essas ilusões, pois está enganando justamente o pessoal sem experiência.

Comment: @Orion mas ela não consegue, ela fica pedindo para os outros resolverem tudo para ela. Ela faz tudo errado, ela deixa tudo inseguro, difícil de usar, causa prejuízos, é um enorme problema.

Comment: Acho que o nosso papel aqui é "pegar pesado" no sentido de deixar claro o que é o que, que é pras pessoas se conscientizarem de onde elas estão, como maneira de criar melhores profissionais, e até mesmo "melhores hobbystas". Ficar passando a mão na cabeça de cara que acha que já ta pronto pode parecer legal num primeiro momento, como um "incentivo" pra pessoa. Mas isso é um deserviço para todo mundo que vem dali pra frente. Toda cadeia de pessoas que aquela pessoa atende é prejudicada por isso. E esse é um problema cada vez pior. Tem mais lixo do que qualquer coisa no mercado.

Comment: Muito obrigado por todas as respostas, mesmo aquelas que não tinham nada com a minha pergunta

Comment: @MayconAlves acabamos usando os comentários como chat paralelo :P Mas a resposta mesmo se encontra no link acima, no quadro amarelo. A sua pergunta vai ser util para que outras pessoas pesquisando encontrem a original.