# Como detectar quando o scroll de um elemento chega ao final sem jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu não sou capaz de entender este código jQuery.

Como posso converter o seguinte código em JavaScript?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table").scroll(function() { 
        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
            console.log("final")
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Fazer isso sem o jQuery seria um tanto trabalhoso e complicado, embora perfeitamente possível. Não prefere aprender como o jQuery funciona ao invés de como você o eliminaria?

Comment: Não posso usar framework, tenho que usar javascript puro

Comment: Acredito que alguém vá responder a pergunta pra você, mas mais importante de ter uma resposta pra isso, já vou avisar: Se você usa jQuery, e não sabe como fazer com o Javascript, eu acredito que esse seja um problema.

Comment: Você sabe o que esse código está fazendo?

Comment: O codigo vai ficar muito mais complicado e dificil de entender se você nao utilizar o JQuery. Um  dos principais objetivos do JQuery é simplificar seleção de elementos do DOM, o que é complicado. Veja esse artigo: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference--net-23703

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade quanto a isso eu discordo. Já faz algum tempo que o jQuery serve apenas para simplificar as coisas. A minha resposta por exemplo, gastei a mesma quantidade de linhas para fazer algo parecido.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters *"jQuery serve apenas para simplificar as coisas"* já faz um tempo não, sempre  :) 
 ele não faz nada que o javascript puro não faça, mas de qualquer jeito, simplificar já é o suficiente não é mesmo?

Comment: Como o @WallaceMaxters comentou, se você não sabe o que o código faz não é uma ajuda para converter o código, mas sim, "convertam esse código para mim", e mesmo em `javascript` puro vai continuar sem entender, seria legal debugar e ver o que cada parte faz, dai você provavelmente vai conseguir converter na próxima vez :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Qual foi a razão da criação do JQuery? Ele é uma biblioteca escrita em JS para simplificar scritps escritos em JS (um pouco redundante, mas é o que é). Vai me dizer que document.getElementById( 'Teste' ).value = 5; é mais simples que $( '#Teste' ).val( 5 ); ?

Comment: @GiovanniEstevam JQuery não é um framework. É uma biblioteca. E não, não é a mesma coisa.

Comment: Enfim, mas vocês entenderam que dá pra sobreviver sem jQuery, né? O propósito do jQuery foi realmente pra facilitar, mas acredito que o Javascript conta com recursos que dispensa muitas coisas hoje em dia. Veja aqui [você não precisa de jQuery :D](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Sim, para isso ao invés do JQuery, use o framewok Vanilla JS :) (espero que entendam a referência)

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade tá aí [O que é Vanilla?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46983/o-que-%C3%A9-o-vanilla-js/47010#47010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que algo mais aproximado seria como abaixo, mas precisaria de saber de mais detalhes sobre porque precisa desse código.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    document.querySelector("#table").addEventListener('scroll', function() { 

        if (this.scrollTop + this.offsetHeight == this.scrollHeight) {
               console.log('final')
        } 
    }); 

})
```

Só uma pequena correção: jQuery é Javascript, não é uma linguagem. No caso, você não está "convertendo para javascript", e sim usando o Javascript puro, sem a biblioteca.

Fiz um exemplo melhor para poder conferir:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    document.querySelector("#table").addEventListener('scroll', function() { 
    
        if (Math.ceil(this.scrollTop) + this.offsetHeight == this.scrollHeight) {
               console.log('final')
        } 
    }); 

})
```

```css
#table{
   max-height: 150px;

   background-color: #ddd;
   
   overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="table">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Até que não ficou tão complicado quanto eu imaginava que ficaria.

Comment: Sim ficou simples mesmo

Comment: Observação: No Snipet, não tá funcionando a soma, kkkkkk. Por isso usei `Math.ceil`

Comment: Como eu comentei acima: Jquery não é um framework, é uma biblioteca. Lembrando que querySelector só esta disponivel depois do IE9, mas como estamos em 2018, ninguém mais se importa. :)

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade já que tocou no assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17501

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade posso estar enganado, mas de onde tirou que `querySelector` não funciona no IE9? Pois se ele existe desde o IE8.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters que tal trocar `window.addEventListener('load'` por `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded'`?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento IE8 a implementação era parcial. Eu só considerei a versão onde a implementação foi total. Veja CanIUse : https://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade você disse IE9, nesse não tem notas no caniuse, logo o comentário ainda estava errado, desculpe a correção prévia, mas é isso. Fora que se ler a nota de implementação parcial não quer dizer que não funciona, ou que funcione 10%, considerando os seletores suportados pelo CSS do IE8 mesmo, provavelmente o parcial ali é um suporte de 90%, tanto que basta ler a nota, o problema do IE8 é somente com tags não reconhecidas (tags do HTML5 por exemplo, o que era um problema do motor CSS no IE8 também, assim como no motor JS), ou seja outros seletores validos no IE8 será Ok ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Só que nos casos onde não funcionava no IE8 ou você usava Jquery ou voce usava uma pollyfill (ex.: https://gist.github.com/chrisjlee/8960575). A discussão aqui é mais, desde quando "podemos" dispensar o JQuery.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade não estou nem entrando na discussão jQueryxVanillaJS, isto era um debate seu e do Wallace, o foco é, você comentou algo e eu apontei que info era um engano de sua parte, o que eu viso tentar colaborar com a comunidade, corrigir o que vejo que é engano, eu sei que não foi por mal, mas deve entender e saber separar o joio do trigo quando alguém corrige alguma informação, o meu comentário ali exclusivamente corrigir uma informação, o que cabe a dizer no máximo: "verdade, engano meu, considere então somente a outra parte" e dariamos o debate terminado ali. Até mais :)

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade já pode bater papo com nóis no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha)?

Comment: Só pra constar Wallace, trocaria `==` por `>=`, creio que isso já resolveria o problema, sem necessitar de `Math.ceil`, mas não testei ainda para ter certeza.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento tentei isso antes de colocar o Math.ceil :\