# Como pegar o tamanho real do scroll?

Tags: javascript, css, rolamento

Estou querendo adquirir a porcentagem que meu scroll está, para manipular css. Porém tenho essas duas variaveis:

`document.documentElement.scrollTop;`
`document.documentElement.scrollHeight;`

A primeira me dá a posição do scroll, e a segunda me dá o tamanho do scroll. Fechou, agora eu só preciso dividir `pos/height` pra ter a porcentagem do scroll, porém no que percebi a variavel `document.documentElement.scrollTop;` quando meu scroll está no final, não dá o mesmo valor que `document.documentElement.scrollHeight;`, ou seja minha porcentagem nunca irá chegar a 100% se eu usar esse cálculo.

Pelo que percebi o `document.documentElement.scrollTop;` não chega no final de fato porque a posição é pega apenas no topo da tela. A uma maneira de eu fazer essa porcentangem de maneira melhor, tipo pegar o tamanho real do scroll?

Comment: Como `scrollTop` marca a posição do topo do viewport, nunca chegará a 100%. Para que seu cálculo funcione basta ajustar o seu valor total, ou seja, seu valor total é o tamanho do scroll menos o tamanho da página (que seria a maior posição que `scrollTop` pode ter). É um problema mais matemático do que de programação, o cálculo ficaria: `100 * scroll_atual / (scroll_total - tamanho_tela)`

Comment: Acho que isso pode te ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312511/como-detectar-quando-o-scroll-de-um-elemento-chega-ao-final-sem-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transformei o comentário em resposta, dessa maneira posso postar um exemplo.

---

Como `scrollTop` marca a posição do topo do *viewport*, nunca chegará a 100%.

Para que seu cálculo funcione basta ajustar o seu valor total, ou seja, seu valor total é o tamanho do scroll menos o tamanho da página (que seria a maior posição que scrollTop pode ter).

É um problema mais matemático do que de programação, o cálculo ficaria:

```
100 * scroll_atual / (scroll_total - tamanho_tela)
```

---

## Exemplo

```js
let elem = document.getElementById('perc')
let doc = document.documentElement

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    let value = parseInt(100 * doc.scrollTop / (doc.scrollHeight - doc.clientHeight))
    elem.innerHTML = value + '%'
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}

#perc {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: white;
  background-color: tomato;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="perc">0%</span>
```

---

## Performance

Lembrando que eventos como [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event#Scroll_event_throttling) e [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event) são disparados muitas vezes por segundo. Então você quer (ou deveria querer) controlar quantas vezes estes evento podem ser disparados.

Para entender melhor pesquise sobre [*throttle* e *debounce* de eventos](https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/).

Comment: Até salvei nos favoritos :D

Comment: Opa, que honra! :D

Comment: Agora olha esse aqui, sem JS, só com CSS https://codepen.io/una/pen/bwrEpZ não é igual nem tem muito a ver com detectar posição do scroll em si, mas é muito massa!