# Como exibir/ocultar um campo(input date) a partir de um campo select?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um select com duas opções: `0` e `1`, 
quando eu seleciono a opção `0`, preciso que exiba um campo e quando selecionar `1`, o campo deve ser ocultado.

Como posso obter esse resultado?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está perceptível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Fiz usando o Jquery. Se você não puder usar o Jquery, implemente o método `.show()` e `.hide()` alternando a propriedade display entre os valores `none` e `''`.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value == 1)
    $('#campo-data').show();
  else
    $('#campo-data').hide();  
});
```

```css
#campo-data {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="0">Esconde campo data</option>
    <option value="1">Mostra campo data</option>
</select>

<input id="campo-data" type="date" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Levando em consideração que:

Valor 0 = Mostrar `input`

Valor 1 = Ocultar `input`

Fiz o seguinte exemplo usando [VanillaJS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46983/o-que-%C3%A9-o-vanilla-js):

```js
function hideShowInput(val) {
    let input = document.getElementById('date');  
    
    if(val == 0) input.style.display = "block";    
    else input.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#date {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="hideShowInput(this.value)">
    <option selected>Selecione uma opção * </option>
    <option value="0">0 - Exibir</option>
    <option value="1">1 - Ocultar</option>
</select> <br><br>


<input id="date" type="date" />
```