# Como receber com $_POST no PHP um valor que foi enviado via URLSearchParams (urlencoded) com fetch do JavaScript Vanilla?

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para receber os dados no php com o $_POST, sendo que os dados vem de uma requisição que é enviada via Fetch do JS. Com FormData (multipart/form-data) eu consigo de boas.

O problema é que no meu caso o valor é proveniente de uma variável. Acho que não seria viável usar o formData pra isso. Então optei pelo URLSearchParams (urlencoded), porém não obtenho êxito. Os dados não estão chegando quando eu tento pegar com $_POST.

**Código JS:**

```js
let optionSelected = selectPlanoDecontas.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].value

fetch('../php/listar-classificacoes-por-plano.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    id_plano: optionSelected
  })
})
```

**Código PHP**

```
 $idPlano = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id_plano', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 print_r($idPlano);
```

Dessa forma abaixo também não funciona:

```
$idPlano = $_POST['id_plano'];
print_r($idPlano);
```

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Eu não consegui reproduzir esse problema. Enviei a mesma requisição (usando `fetch` com _Content-Type_ definido `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` pelo uso de `URLSearchParams` (assim como você fez) e recebi corretamente, pelo PHP, o parâmetro `id_plano`.

Comment: Conseguiu receber com $_POST ?

Comment: Como disse acima, sim. [Veja aqui o que eu fiz.](https://github.com/lffg2/sopt/tree/main/snippets/508839)

Comment: Poxa, exatamente igual. Não sei o porquê no meu exemplo não funciona.

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger  Como você esta fazendo para  saber que `print_r($idPlano);` não esta funcionando?  acessar diretamente a url `../listar-classificacoes-por-plano.php` não vai funcionar por que o `fetch` não recarrega a pagina ao executar. Uma opção seria você usar as ferramentas de desenvolvedor do seu navegador para saber o que o servidor esta respondendo.

Comment: @Juven_v, eu faço diretamente no arquivo. Apesar de não recarregar a página, o fetch faz a requisição ao arquivo, certo ? Então, acessando o arquivo php, acredito que dê pra ver esse saída do print_r na "Network", que é o que estou fazendo.

Comment: Você já verificou os headers da requisição para ver como e que dados estão chegando?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, havia verificado sim. Estava tudo certo. Status, etc ... O problema era que eu não estava usando o then. Vou elaborar uma resposta.

Comment: @GatodeSchrödinger, mas aí já foge da pergunta, não? Afinal, os dados estão, de fato, sendo recebidos pelo PHP! :-)

Comment: @LuizFelipe, não, não estavam. Só passou a ser recebido depois que usamos o then() no fetch(). Por um motivo inexplicável (ou entendível pela questão da promisse), o fetch só completa a requisição, e envia os dados para o backend, quando tem uma then() para garantir o retorno de sua promisse. Ou um outro then(), que receba o seu retorno e trate-o.

Comment: ... Após eu inserir o then(), os dados começaram a chegar no arquivo PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O problema era que eu não estava usando o "then()". Por ser uma **Promisse**, o fetch() necessita que seja utilizado o "then()" para que seja retornado o seu **resolve()**, ou o "catch()", para que seja retornado o seu **reject()**.

Segue abaixo as duas formas que eu consegui fazer, tanto com o **URLsearchparams** tanto com o **formData**:

**Com formData**

```js
let optionSelected = selectPlanoDecontas.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].value

let form = new FormData()

form.append('id_plano', optionSelected)

fetch('../php/listar-classificacoes-por-plano.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: dataForm
})
.then(response => {

}) 
.catch(error => {

})
```

**Com URLsearchParams**

```js
let optionSelected = selectPlanoDecontas.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].value

fetch('../php/listar-classificacoes-por-plano.php', {
    method: 'POST',
  body: new URLSearchParams({
    id_plano: optionSelected
  })
})
.then(response => {
  
})
.catch(error => {

})
```

Essas são as duas maneiras que encontrei para fazer (existem outras). Tanto com formData quanto com URLsearchParams.

Answer (score -1):

O .then e o .catch tratam a resposta do backend

> Os dados não estão chegando quando eu tento pegar com $_POST.

Eu reproduzi algo similar ao o que provavelmente você utiliza no seu [Vanilla JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46983/o-que-%C3%A9-o-vanilla-js)

```
<?php
// test.php

$idPlano = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id_plano', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

echo '<pre>';
echo 'var_dump(idPlano): ';
echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump($idPlano);

echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'var_dump($_POST): ' ;
echo PHP_EOL;
var_dump($_POST);
```

Arquivo .html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="select-teste">
        <option value="valor_1">Valor 1</option>
        <option value="valor_2">Valor 2</option>
    </select>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var selected = document.getElementById('select-teste');
    selected.onchange = function(selected) { 
        let optionSelected = this.options[selected.target.options.selectedIndex].value;
        
        fetch('test.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                id_plano: optionSelected
            })
        });

    }
    
</script>
</html>
```

Veja a saída do var_dump

[image: var_dump]

Ou seja, os dados chegam no back-end. Feito isso aí sim você processa a sua lógica e retorna a resposta para que com .then e .catch você trate no front-end