# Como editar códigos gigantescos?

Tags: estilo-de-codificação, organização-de-projeto

É uma dúvida que tenho desde que comecei a ler códigos. Vejo algumas classes com mil, dois mil, milhares de linhas.

Como um programador pode editar tanta coisa sem "se perder" no meio de tanta coisa?

Mesmo comentando o código, usando nomes lógicos para as variáveis, procedimentos/funções etc, ainda assim fica muito difícil mudar até mesmo o nome de uma variável no escopo, tendo assim que mudar todas as entradas e saídas no código. No momento estou desenvolvendo um código para reserva de hotéis (um trabalho da faculdade, em grupo). O código está com aproximadamente mil linhas e ninguém consegue mais administrar tanta coisa, mesmo com comentários, `switchs`, `if` aninhado etc.

No geral, quero saber se existe alguma regra ou algum macete usado por programadores profissionais para conseguirem editar códigos enormes sem se perderem no meio dos mesmos. Espero não ter sido muito vago. Procurei por respostas em fóruns mas sem sucesso.

Comment: Se o código for bem escrito, não vai sofrer _tanto_. Caso contrário, boa sorte.

Comment: Vc só precisa editar o que vc quer mudar. O que está funcionando, à princípio, vc não deve mexer. É bom apenas dar uma revisada pra ver se algo pode ser melhorado. É trabalho de "formiguinha" mesmo. Vai vendo linha por linha se existem coisas que podem ser otimizadas para deixar o código mais enxuto, e por aí vai.

Comment: Digamos que nesse trabalho em grupo uma pessoa sozinha escreveu 1000 linhas de código. Eu falei que era desnecessário e que ninguém saberia lidar com tanta informação, o mesmo não aceitou a opinião e disse que vai ser do jeito dele. Acho que pelo jeito vou ter que fazer papel de formiguinha e sair catando mesmo. Infelizmente terei que lidar novamente com pessoas inflexíveis.

Comment: Padrões de projetos são para isso: soluções comuns para problemas comuns. Ao utilizá-los você não precisa analisar linha a linha do código.

Comment: Acredite se quiser => [o Método possui 34 mil linhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197317/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Vejo algumas classes com mil, dois mil, milhares de linhas

Mil linhas é muito? "Acho" que não.

> Como um programador pode editar tanta coisa sem "se perder" no meio de tanta coisa?

Fazendo o que os computadores fazem muito bem e que os humanos deveriam saber fazer o tempo todo: [dividindo para conquistar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm).

Lide com uma parte de cada vez. Construa cada parte para que ela dependa minimamente de outras partes. Planeje antes. Crie um resumo daquilo tudo. Entenda o que está fazendo. Não coloque nada que não precise ali.

Fazer grande, bagunçado, ineficiente é fácil, fazer organizado, pequeno e eficiente é difícil, mas isso se paga sozinho. É assim que as pessoas administram grandes bases de código, fazendo certo e decupado de acordo com a responsabilidade de cada coisa, colocando na função e na estrutura de dados só o que ela faz, sem depender de nada externo sem necessidade e dar bons nomes fazem tudo ficar simples.

Quando separa e lida com uma parte de cada vez não tem nada de gigantesco.

Um bom IDE pode ajudar. Ele é só uma ferramenta de ajuda, tem que saber usá-lo corretamente.

> Mesmo comentando o código, usando nomes lógicos para as variáveis, procedimentos/funções, etc., ainda assim fica muito difícil mudar até mesmo o nome de uma variável no escopo, tendo assim que mudar todas as entradas e saídas no código.

Me parece ser coisas incongruentes. Se está dando nomes bons por que [precisa comentar o código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15488/101) Eu acho que sei a resposta, não está dando nomes bons.

Na verdade [comentário costuma fazer mais mal do que bem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56751/101).

Se mudar o nome de uma variável no escopo está difícil este escopo deve estar muito errado.

Acho que as pessoas fazem funções muito longas, obviamente com muitas variáveis, e colocam a declaração da variável longe do seu uso e de forma pouco lógica. O erro começa aí.

A descrição mostra sintomas de outros problemas.

> No momento estou desenvolvendo um código para reserva de hotéis (um trabalho da faculdade, em grupo). O código está com aproximadamente mil linhas e ninguém consegue mais administrar tanta coisa, mesmo com comentários, `switchs`, `if` aninhado etc.

Além de ser muito complicado pode ser que na verdade ainda não entendem o que estão fazendo. É óbvio que se aprende coisas com um monte de lacuna não tem como usar o que aprendeu de forma adequada. E a maioria das pessoas aprendem desta forma. Elas fazem algo, mas não entendem o que estão fazendo, aí quando sai da complexidade mínima de um exercício isolado e vai para a complexidade real de um problema de verdade ela não consegue mais administrar aquilo.

E tem muito caso que não é saber programação, é não saber matemática (não falo de decorar fórmulas), comunicação e expressão, método científico, filosofia (sim, ela é importante para a lógica correta), e outras coisas básicas que constroem a capacidade da pessoa lidar com problemas.

Vou descartar a hipótese de problemas cognitivos da pessoa, mas tem muito caso assim.

> No geral, quero saber se existe alguma regra ou algum macete usado por programadores profissionais para conseguirem editar códigos enormes sem se perderem no meio dos mesmos.

Regra mágica não tem não. É evoluir aos poucos, não querer queimar etapas, se dedicar, procurar melhor cada aspecto individual que está tendo dificuldade, pedir ajuda com coisas específicas, treinar, pedir *feedback* de pessoas experientes, reconhecidas (de verdade) e confrontar com o *feddback* de outras pessoas que pensam diferente. E claro, organizar e simplificar (mas antes tem que aprender fazer isto).

> Digamos que nesse trabalho em grupo uma pessoa sozinha escreveu 1000 linhas de código. Eu falei que era desnecessário

Se é desnecessário faça menor. Se a equipe não aceita faça o seu e apresente, afinal algumas poucas centenas de linhas dá para fazer em algumas horas, se já está definido e só precisa codificar talvez leve minutos.

Eu poderia até dizer outras coisas sobre isto, mas ficaria muito fora de escopo.

Answer (score 1):

Se você tiver um sistema bem documentado, não importa o tamanho do código é fácil identificar o que cada método faz dentro de uma classe, outra coisa, uma documentação com requisitos bem definidos não há necessidade de alterar nome de variável, no máximo acrescentar ou diminuir.