# Qual é o termo correto para chamar alguém que faz códigos em HTML?

Tags: html, terminologia

**HTML** - Hipertext Markup Language

Todos sabemos que HTML é uma linguagem de marcação de texto e não de programação, porém qual seria o termo correto de chamar alguém que está escrevendo em HTML?

Poderíamos dizer que ele está programando? Podemos chama-lo de programador?

Vamos supor que ele utilize apenas HTML e CSS e não utilize nenhuma linguagem de programação.

Qual é a definição correta?

Sou programador PHP, porém muitas vezes antes de colocar meu template para o código eu digo que estou programando. Porém algumas pessoas dizem que apenas estou programando quando utilizo comandos de programação. (PHP ou Javascript)

Compreendo completamente que HTML é uma linguagem de marcação de texto, mas a dúvida está em como chamar alguém que **"programa"** em HTML.

O correto seria dizer, **"estou escrevendo em HTML?"** , **Estou programando em HTML?**. Parece boba esta pergunta, mas existem muitas pessoas que reclamam do termo programar em HTML.

Claro que não digo isto quando estou programando com PHP, porém quando você está criando um layout em bootstrap por exemplo, muita gente enche o saco dizendo que você não está programando.

Comment: Marcador? hahahaha.

Comment: Etiquetador... :v

Comment: Frango ? To brincando

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Há várias terminologias que não estão erradas, porém algumas se adequam mais do que outras.

> Em computação, um programador, desenvolvedor, coder ou engenheiro de software refere-se a alguém que faz programação de computadores e escreve software.
>   [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programador)

Só nessa frase já temos quatro nomenclaturas para uma "mesma" profissão. Mas vamos nos ater em "programador" e "desenvolvedor".

Embora uma mesma pessoa possa ser um "programador" e "desenvolvedor" e em um mesmo trabalho ele pode estar aplicando as "duas funções", mas há uma diferença entre as duas. Então quais são as diferenças de um programador para um desenvolvedor?

Um **programador** trabalha com aquilo que pode ser programado, ou seja, ele cria um programa através de rotinas lógicas. **[O HTML não é uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101)** e sim de marcação, por isso **não existe programador HTML**.

Um **desenvolvedor** cria alguma coisa, ou desenvolve algo já criado, ou seja ele pode desenvolver um programa, um *layout*, uma regra, uma função, uma rotina e etc. Este é o termo mais genérico e que se aplica a várias áreas engenharia de software como:

- Desenvolvimento de jogos;
- Desenvolvimento de app;
- Desenvolvimento de sites;
- Desenvolvimento de sistemas (programas);
- etc.

Porém o "Desenvolvedor" pode ser sub-categorizado em mais algumas terminologia no ramo da programação. Uma delas é o **Desenvolvedor Web** que não se aplica apenas a um tipo de desenvolvimento, ou seja, há vários meios de se desenvolver para web além do HTML, um desenvolvedor web pode faze-lo com PHP, ASP, ASP.NET, C#, Java, Flash (Isso ainda é utilizado na web?), Javascript e etc. Então surgiu duas terminologias que são: **Desenvolvedor Back-End** e **Desenvolvedor Front-End**. Mas antes de falar dessas duas, vamos falar de uma que era bem utilizada para o profissional que desenvolvia sites (com HTML e etc) a algum tempo atrás, mas hoje não é tão mencionado como antes, que é o **Web Designer**.

Um **Web Designer** não precisa necessariamente escrever algum código HTML para ser chamado assim (Pois o termo *designer* significa desenhista), muitas vezes a pessoa apenas desenha um *layout* de site, ou e-mail, ou banner eletrônico e etc em um editor de imagens e passa essa imagem para a pessoa que escreve o HTML.

Então quem é essa "pessoa que escreve o HTML"? Calma, já vamos chegar lá...

**Desenvolvedor Back-End** é aquele que cuida da "parte de trás" do software. Geralmente feitas com linguagens server-side como PHP, ASP, C# e etc. Este pode ser o mesmo que escreve o HTML, ou pode ser outro na fila do desenvolvimento que recebe o código HTML para continuar no desenvolvimento do software.

E por fim, o **Desenvolvedor Front-End**, este é aquele que cuida da "parte da frente" ou visivel do software. Geralmente feita com HTML, CSS e Javascript. Então poderíamos chamar quem escreve códigos HTML de "Desenvolvedor Front-End", porém nem só de HTML vive um Desenvolvedor Front-End (Posso dizer, pois trabalho na área), muitos outros recursos são necessários para realizar algo significativo na parte do front-end.

Enfim, se a pessoa trabalha apenas com HTML, podemos chama-lo de **marcador**, pois não estará fazendo nada mais do que isso. Mas se ele desenvolve utilizando HTML e seus amigos inseparáveis, o CSS e Javascript, então **ele é um Desenvolvedor Front-End**.

Comment: Concordo com o que foi dito, porém ainda acredito que seja mais elegante dizer que você está programando. Não necessariamente ele é um desenvolvedor front end, ele poderia ser um desenvolvedor full stack. Por que nenhum sistema é construído sem sua interface, pois até mesmo a tela preta do cmd é uma espécie de interface gráfica para o usuário digitar comandos.

Por isto acredito que quando a pessoa faz os códigos HTML ele está programando bytes e programando e arquitetando a estrutura do código.

Answer (score 17):

Embora seja uma grande contraversão, o ideal seria chamá-lo de **`Web Developer`** (Desenvolvedor Web)

- Se você é mais voltado para o design, você é então um **`Web Designer`**.
- Se você é mais voltado para a programação (além do HTML), você é um **`Programador Web`**.

**Curiosidades**

**`Código`** é desenvolvido. **`Markup`** é escrito.

[Veja quem](http://ask.slashdot.org/story/09/04/14/1434206/what-do-you-call-people-who-do-html) já discutiu a respeito.

Comment: Então seria correto dizer estou programando um layout em bootstrap? Ou estou programando em HTML?

Comment: Eu imagino, na minha humilde opinião, que você está "desenhando" (como um `web designer`) um layout HTML.

Comment: É estranho dizer que você está desenhando quando na verdade você está escrevendo. (Mesmo que depois vire um layout).

Comment: Opa, sim, é verdade...mas design é `desenho`, por mais que na prática você está pintando (pintor) ou escrevendo (web designer), hehe. É mais um conceito do que um termo literal

Comment: Então eu digo que estou escrevendo em HTML ou Desenvolvendo um layout em HTML? Ou será que desenhando em HTML mesmo?

Comment: Com relação à tarefa (e não à nomenclatura), eu acho que `desenvolvendo um layout HTML` ou `desenhando um layout HTML` estão em pleno acordo. Quando você inclui "HTML", já remove da frase a ideia de "desenho" e inclui a ideia de "escrita".

Answer (score 4):

Normalmente quem fica encarregado de HTML, CSS, Javascript e etc, é um Front-End. Então acredito que essa seria a definição certa nesse contexto.

Quanto a programar ou escrever isso depende de pessoa para pessoa. Eu particularmente não falo "programar" em HTML, pois acho que só faz sentido "programar" se houver logica, o que no caso de HTML não tem.

Comment: Eu programo em PHP, Java, Javascript, C, C#, Object Pascal. E nem pro isto acho errado o termo programar em HTML, é mais comum utilizar este termo do que escrever em HTML. 

Agora Javascript não é linguagem de marcação de texto, é linguagem de programação.

Programar não seria tudo que envolve comandos? SQL (Structured Query Language) por exemplo... Seria errado dizer: "Estou programando uma query"?

Muitas querys não envolvem programação, mas envolvem lógica. Porém não é correto dizer que layouts não envolvem lógica.

Comment: Eu não disse que acho errado e sim concordo com quase tudo. Mas acredito que layout é estrutural, a logica esta na estrutura, na forma como é construida, então não acho que layout tenha logica propriamente dita.

Comment: O front-end é o que ele está construindo, não? Ele seria um *front-end **developer***.

Answer (score 2):

Essa dúvida trata mais de linguagem gramatical do que de terminologia tecnológica.

**Caso 1:**
*Estou trabalhando em um sistema para WEB onde eu desenvolverei todo o sistema em PHP e utilizarei do HTML para montar minha interface. Neste momento eu estou escrevendo o HTML da página de Login.* Então:
Se quero me referir ao todo: *Estou programando ou estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP.*
Se quero ser específico no que estou fazendo agora: *Estou escrevendo um HTML para a tela de login.*

**Caso 2:**
*Você está em um ônibus à caminho do trabalho e alguém te liga e pergunta "O que está fazendo?"*
Bom, naturalmente responderemos **"Estou no ônibus, à caminho do trabalho."**. Raramente seremos específicos ao ponto de dizer **"Falando com você ao telefone!"**.

Note que é uma questão de contexto. Sabemos que não se programa em HTML. Ficar dizendo o tempo todo **"Ain, não se programa em HTML, você escreve em HTML porque HTML é uma linguagem de marcação de texto e não de programação"** tem mais relação com querer aparecer, menosprezar os conhecimentos de alguém ou ficar tirando sarro. A menos que estejamos no campo didático sobre o tema e isso não é a maioria dos casos. O resto é cagação de regra e deve ser respeitado mesmo é o contexto.

*Se você integra um time de desenvolvimento de um sistema, mas cuida apenas da parte do banco de dados:* **Você está sim desenvolvendo um sistema**, mas não é um desenvolvedor de software ou programador, suas atribuições são outras;
*Se você desenvolve um sistema e trata do Front-end e do Back-end*, então **você está sim desenvolvendo ou programando, mesmo quando escreve HTML**;
*Mas se seu supervisor pergunta, das tarefas referente ao desenvolvimento, qual está sendo executada neste momento*, então **você, neste momento, está escrevendo o HTML da tela "X"**.

Answer (score 0):

Gosto de pesquisar os significado real da palavra e comparar com a forma que utilizamos a palavra em nosso meio.

Nessa caso se para pra pensar qual o significado de "programar" podemos aceitar que uma pessoa esta programando um HTML ou algo no draw.io

SIM PRA MIM TAMBÉM É BIZRRO FALAR ISSO MAS:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então como podemos ver na tradução ai que o google faz a gente pode fazer uma associação que no final a gente ta escrevendo ou no caso "fazendo algumas marcações" onde, mais tarde um computador irá interpretar esses passos que está escrito em HTML.

Ou até mesmo um desenvolvedor vai seguir passos desenhados por um desing para fazer uma tela que posteriormente um computador vai seguir os passos do desenvolvedor para exibir a tela desenvolvida em HTLM, JavaScript, PHP, o que seja

EU ACHO, que a questão só esta em como abstraímos as coisa. e se formos ver, quando estamos PROGRAMANDO "de fato" estamos fazendo abstrações para o computador interpretar, independente da linguagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: datilógrafo,
Pode ser um de seus adjetivos, pois é aquele que usa uma 'maquina' de escrever

Answer (score -6):

Programador HTML.

"As linguagens de programação de computadores, de acordo com o catálogo do sítio "The Language List", podem ser classificadas segundo suas características funcionais. A seguir apresentam-se, da lista indicada, as mais importantes:

**Linguagem Procedural** - possibilita o desenvolvimento da programação de forma estruturada, permitindo a construção de rotinas por meio de módulos de procedimentos ou de funções que estejam interligados, sendo por vezes classificada como linguagem interpretativa.

**Linguagem declarativa** - possibilita o desenvolvimento de programação normalmente estática, sendo por vezes classificada como *LINGUAGEM DE MARCAÇÃO*.

**Linguagem orientada a objetos** - permite o desenvolvimento de composições e interações de programas entre várias unidades de programas denominadas objetos, em que objeto é um elemento abstrato que representa uma entidade do mundo real em um computador.

**Linguagem concorrente** - possibilita o desenvolvimento de programas com características de execução de rotinas em paralelo e não da forma sequencial normalmente encontrada nas outras categorias.

**Linguagem de consulta** - garante acesso para a extração de informações em bases de dados existentes em programas de gerenciamento de bancos de dados.

**Linguagem de especificação** - define a documentação descritiva em alto nível de um sistema, sendo por vezes classificada como linguagem de projeto de programação.

No aspecto de operação de uma linguagem de programação de computadores, esta pode ser aplicada para o desenvolvimento da programação científica, comercial ou de uso geral. Não existem motivos partidários para achar que uma linguagem de programação é melhor do que a outra, uma vez que cada linguagem é desenvolvida para atender a determinados problemas e aplicações."

José Augusto N. G. Manzano e Jayr Figueiredo de Oliveira / Algoritmos - lógica para desenvolvimento de programação de computadores. 28ª edição.

Comment: No caso, em qual dessas que você mencionou que o HTML se encaixaria?

Comment: Linguagem declarativa - possibilita o desenvolvimento de programação normalmente estática, sendo por vezes classificada como linguagem de marcação. (2º item)