# O Excel é uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: microsoft-excel, característica-linguagem

Não, não estou pedindo opinião. Estou criando esta pergunta aqui porque hoje achei esta improvável pergunta:

[HTML é uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35547/html-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o?lq=1)

E, confesso, votei positivo no segundo comentário (imagem abaixo) da principal resposta:

[image: Comentários]

Então a pergunta é uma só, mas acho que comporta uma pequena divisão:

- A [máquina teórica mínima](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_Turing_universal) de *Turing* é a única forma (ou a mais aceita) para se determinar o que é uma linguagem de programação?
- Em assim sendo, de acordo com Turing o Excel é mesmo uma linguagem de programação? (Na hipótese da resposta da primeira pergunta ser negativa, informe de acordo com qual método você baseou sua resposta).

Comment: Softwares como Excel , Crystal Reports etc ficam em um "limbo" entre uma Linguagem de Programação é um software que pode ser programado , a resposta vai ser DEPENDE , depende de como se define uma LP.

Comment: Mas a forma de definir uma LP não é algo definido? Além do método de Turing, qual outro pode ser aplicado? @Motta

Comment: Não sei , será que teremos de ter esta definição ? Software que aceita comando de voz é "linguagem de programação" , digo,  o comando de voz ?

Comment: Mas este tipo de discussão não é o foco deste site.

Comment: Então @Motta, eu vejo como uma pergunta objetiva. Ou é ou não é.

Comment: @Motta comando de voz é uma entrada de dados, só isto.

Comment: Se você chamar a linguagem das fórmulas, como, SE(), SOMA(), etc de Excel, eu diria que é sim. Se você disser que o Excel é só uma "casca" e dentro tem uma linguagem anônima, com as funções SE(), SOMA(), etc, eu diria que essa tal coisa, talvez sem nome próprio, é uma linguagem de programação, e Excel é a IDE. Nem vou entrar no mérito do VBA, pois entendo ser uma coisa fora do escopo da pergunta. VBA é uma linguagem de programação, mas é um acessório do Excel. Você pode usar o Excel, programar dentro dele, e nem passar perto de VBA.

Comment: É um software. E, [o mais perigoso do mundo](http://www.forbes.com/sites/timworstall/2013/02/13/microsofts-excel-might-be-the-most-dangerous-software-on-the-planet/).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

O que define o que é uma linguagem de programação?

Você encontrará várias definições. Na [Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o):

> Uma linguagem de programação é um método padronizado para comunicar instruções para um computador.[1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) É um conjunto de regras sintáticas e semânticas usadas para definir um programa de computador.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)
>
> [Nota 1] Permite que um programador especifique precisamente sobre quais dados um computador vai atuar, como estes dados serão armazenados ou transmitidos e quais ações devem ser tomadas sob várias circunstâncias. Linguagens de programação podem ser usadas para expressar algoritmos com precisão.

Se continuarmos lendo o artigo (mesmo [em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)) encontraremos várias informações que ajudam definir o que se espera de uma linguagem de programação e até as várias classificações delas. Notamos que não podemos nos prender ao jeito clássico que conhecemos linguagens como C, Java, C#, JavaScript, PHP, etc.

O Excel se encaixa nessas definições.

Um dos critérios para definir se uma linguagem é de programação pode ser se ela é [*Turing Complete*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness). Este é único critério objetivo que conheço para definir se a linguagem tem capacidade completa de programação. Algumas pessoas podem discordar. Nunca encontrei uma definição canônica e definitiva que indique isto. Também nunca vi algo plausível que indique que isto não é um bom critério.

Se existe um critério objetivo, critérios mais subjetivos obviamente não são bons para decidir alguma coisa. Alguém conhece um critério melhor?

Aí eu fico pensando como alguém em sã consciência pode considerar que um software que pode resolver qualquer problema computacional de forma totalmente programável sem precisar de ajuda externa pode não ser uma linguagem de programação? É mais polêmico dizer que SQL (padrão) é uma linguagem de programação, porque existem problemas que ela não consegue resolver.

Então Excel (e não VBA, que obviamente também é) é uma linguagem de programação. Se discorda, ok. Não vai mudar a vida de ninguém. Mas, se possível, demonstre onde existe uma falha nesta definição. Nunca achei.

Alguns locais onde se discute isto:

- http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MicrosoftExcelProgrammingLanguage
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=429505
- http://www.felienne.com/archives/2974

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 21):

Considero que aqui estejam a ser misturados alguns conceitos:

- Linguagem de programação
- Turing machine
- Excel
- Funções do Excel

Na minha opinião [a Wiki](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) tem um boa definição do que é uma linguagem de programação:

> Uma linguagem de programação é um método padronizado para comunicar
>   instruções para um computador.[1](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o) É um conjunto de regras sintáticas e
>   semânticas usadas para definir um programa de computador.[2](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-SE-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) [Nota 1]
>   Permite que um programador especifique precisamente sobre quais dados
>   um computador vai atuar, como estes dados serão armazenados ou
>   transmitidos e quais ações devem ser tomadas sob várias
>   circunstâncias.

Turing machine na prática é qualquer mecanismo que acabe por repetir uma sequência de instruções indefinidamente. Esta é uma simplificação dada do recurso que o OP disponibilizou, com ênfase minha:

> Toda máquina de Turing **computa uma certa função computável parcial**
>   **fixa** a partir de uma cadeia como entrada formada pelos símbolos de seu
>   alfabeto

Quando alguém se refere ao Excel normalmente está-se a referir ao programa e à sua utilidade prática, mas nem tanto, relativamente às funções disponibilizadas.

As funções do Excel sim, formam uma linguagem de programação, porque respeitam a definição supra-citada. Chamo particular atenção para a existência de funções capazes de fazer controlo de fluxo [tal como a função Se](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-SE-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2).

E, muito provavelmente, também é uma linguagem de programação Turing Complete, ou seja, poderá ser possível um programa que execute um conjunto determinado de instruções indefinidamente. Senão for, a existência de macros faz com que seja, inquestionavelmente.

Answer (score 10):

Eu não considero o **Excel** uma [Linguagem de Programação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o), o considero uma IDE para desenvolvimento VBA, assim como o Access que é uma IDE para o VBA e também um SGDB. O Microsoft Office Excel é um editor de planilhas

Existe uma diferença entre linguagem de programação e IDE ou interpretador de comandos!

Desde 1993, o Excel tem incluído o Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), uma linguagem de programação baseada no Visual Basic que adiciona a capacidade de automatizar tarefas no Excel e prover funções definidas pelo utilizador (UDF, user defined functions), para uso em pastas de trabalho.

O VBA é um complemento poderoso ao aplicativo que, em versões posteriores, inclui um ambiente integrado de desenvolvimento (IDE, integrated development environment). A gravação de macros pode produzir código VBA que replica ações do usuário, desse modo permitindo automação simples de tarefas cotidianas. O VBA permite a criação de formulários e controles dentro da pasta de trabalho para comunicação com o usuário. A linguagem suporta o uso (mas não a criação) de DLLs ActiveX (COM); versões posteriores adicionaram suporte a módulos de classe, permitindo o uso de técnicas básicas de programação orientada a objetos (POO).

Comment: Então Junior, mas qual a diferença entre linguagem de programação e IDE ou interpretador de comandos, e porque o Excel, que atende a todos os requisitos, não é uma linguagem de programação? Os dois últimos parágrafos da resposta explicam as funções do VBA, mas não explicam porque o Excel (que atende(??) aos requisitos da máquina virtual mínima de Turing), não é uma linguagem de programação, e acho que isto passa por explicar a diferença entre linguagem de programação e IDE ou interpretador de comandos...

Comment: O Access tem mais potencial para ser uma linguagem de programação do que o Excel, Linguagem de programação editei a resposta com uma boa definição! IDE vamos dizer ser um programa capaz de criar/desenvolver programas utilizando linguagens de programação, te dou como exemplo o Notepad, com ele você pode criar paginas HTML, PHP dentre outras, é como se ele fosse uma IDE Web! Assim como o Word que também possui acesso ao VBA.

Comment: Um detalhe, você pode criar um editor de planilhas que aceite condições e padrões de formulas, assim como funciona o Excel, e não estaria criando uma nova linguagem!

Answer (score 10):

As rotinas no Excel são providas pelo VBA.

O VBA, sim, é uma linguagem de programação.

O Excel, de forma resumida, é apenas uma planilha. Podemos dizer que é uma calculadora.

Então a pergunta é quase como dizer se uma calculadora é uma linguagem de programação.

É algo similar entre HTML e JavaScript. O HTML não é linguagem de programação. É uma linguagem de marcação de texto, como o próprio nome diz.

Quem dá vida, automação, etc, ao HTML, é a linguagem de programação JavaScript.

É algo similar também entre o Flash e o Action Script, ou o AutoCAD e LISP.

REsumindo, para entender se algo é ou não uma linguagem de programação, basta entender a definição de "Linguagem de programação".

Algumas respostas postadas por outros colegas mencionam o assunto.

Answer (score -4):

Na minha opinião SIM, um arquivo .xlsx pode conter uma linguagem de programação à depender do que é capaz de executar. Basta buscar vários artigos científicos que apresentam softwares desenvolvidos em Excel (lá fora amplamente aceitos como Spreadsheet programs) (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0098300410000531; http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S009830040900274X) 
O Excel é uma IDE que, entre outras coisas, permite o usuário criar algoritmos que combinam funções lógicas, matemáticas, estatísticas, etc. próprias do Excel mesmo sem programação VBA, podendo gerar portanto um arquivo (.xlsx) que pode ser considerado um software (ainda que este software seja dependente da própria IDE onde foi criado para rodar).
Portanto, na prática, vários softwares atuais (softwares que ninguém questiona possuir uma linguagem de programação própria já que foram desenvolvidos em C++, R, VB, Java, Pascal, etc.) podem ser facilmente substituídos por planilhas eletrônicas. 
E qual seria a linguagem de um Spreadsheet Program? 
Notem que o Excel se utiliza de elementos de programação de várias outras linguagens, se apropriando de termos e lógicas de criação de algoritmos semelhantes à outros IDEs. A linguagem, portanto, é própria. Poderia ser mencionada apenas como linguagem do Excel. Não sei se há uma forma padrão mais usual para se mencionar esta linguagem. Se precisarem do código (textualmente) basta marcar a opção "mostrar fórmulas" no Excel e salvar o arquivo como .XML em um bloco de notas. Pronto, lá estará a extensa lista de fórmulas de todas as células do SpreadSheet program criado.

Comment: Se seguir a lógica que gerar outro arquivo é motivação para ser uma linguagem de programação, então o programa `fsutil` (Windows) ou o `touch` (Linux) também seriam "linguagens". Gerar arquivos contendo algo não é capacidade exclusiva de linguagens, acho que você deve procurar ler sobre "Turing Complete", ou ainda melhor, para facilitar ler as respostas que já existem na pergunta e não se basear em "achismo" (quando se diz "eu acho" ou "na minha opinião").