# O que caracteriza uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: característica-linguagem, terminologia, independente-de-linguagem, design-de-linguagem

Há muito tempo atrás vi em laboratório um "programa" chamado [POV-Ray](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/POV-Ray) e uma dúvida me instigou. O professor disse que é uma "**linguagem de programação**" e argumentou, ora tem código fonte, sintaxe, semântica e compilador logo é uma linguagem de programação.

É correto fazer tal afirmação usando esses argumentos?

Como podemos definir uma linguagem de programação? Quais elementos se faz necessário estar presente para que seja enquadrado?

Comment: Relacionada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/3084

Comment: Acho esta resposta perfeita para o caso: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99665/3635 além da já citada pelo @cantoni

Comment: Ou duplicata de uma delas? Algum dos links acima responde à sua dúvida?

Comment: @bfavaretto eu estava marcando como duplicata mesmo :) É que eu queria entender o que ele estava dizendo de POV-ray. Tavelz seria melhor ele ter perguntando "pov-ray é uma linguagem de programação?"

Comment: lendo essa resposta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99666/12032 e essa http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99665/12032 fiquei na mesma quando não tinha lido nenhuma das duas quer dizer que sendo uma Turing Complete já é considerado uma linguagem de programação? bastar ter opção de loop infinito ?

Comment: Reabri a pergunta porque a que eu tinha indicado como duplicata não estava boa para o que você quer saber. Mas ainda acho que a outra responde. E como assim "basta ter um loop infinito"? Não é isso que define o que é Turing Complete.

Comment: Talvez a pergunta certa a se fazer é o que é uma linguagem de programação **de propósito geral**. Pois uma linguagem pode não ser Turing completa e ainda assim ser usada para "programar" (no sentido de exercer controle sobre uma ferramenta automatizada). SQL, que eu saiba, não é Turing completa, mas é usada para "programar" um banco de dados. GLSL possui escopo muito limitado, mas é usada pra "programar" a GPU. Etc. Eu duvido que um sistema de *raytracing* seja Turing completo, mas se esse POV-Ray permite controlar o processo de geração da imagem, eu diria sim que ele é "de programação".

Comment: @mgibsonbr é neste sentido mesmo a minha pergunta, em se tratando de **linguagem de programação** quais os requisitos necessarios para que seja classificado como tal

Comment: @SneepSNinjA tem alguma coisa que possa fazer para melhorar a resposta?

Comment: Eu gostaria de uma resposta cabal, talvez você tenha detalhado demais a sua resposta e eu não tenha conseguido entender, posso dizer então que a linguagem de programação é toda aquela que consegue implementar uma maquina de turing ?

Comment: @SneepSNinjA exatamente isto. Se fosse resumir em uma frase.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

## A teoria

A definição mais aceita é que **a linguagem precisa ser [*Turing-Complete*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), ou que pode simular a [*Universal Turing Machine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine) para ser considerada de programação**. Isso significa que qualquer [função que pode ser matematicamente calculada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_function) de alguma forma, deve ser possível ser expressada, e consequentemente executada em sua plenitude, gerando resultados corretos e esperados através dessas linguagens.

A teoria não fala da forma como isso pode ser obtido, mas obviamente é preciso conseguir o objetivo por meios próprios, ela não pode depender de formas externas ao que foi definida nela para alcançar o resultado.

A teoria não fala qual é o meio concreto de execução. Não importa que isso seja convertido para outra linguagem ou código que realmente permita executar o cálculo, é normal que isso aconteça.

A teoria também não fala sobre a arquitetura da máquina que vai executar, não precisa ser elétrica, não precisa ter um processador.

Ela deixa em aberto que a linguagem possa expressar o problema da forma mais simples ou mais complexa, facilitando ou dificultando para humanos ou máquinas entenderem o que é aquilo (obviamente estas duas características são antagônicas, o que é fácil para o primeiro, é difícil para o segundo e vice-versa). Não importa se ela é representada por bits ou algo mais [esotérico](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Turing_tarpit) que isto (sim é possível algo [maluco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), [inventado](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Iota)) ou um texto poético usando versos pinçados dos grandes autores lusófonos no melhor e mais rebuscado português (se é que isto é possível existir).

## Hardware

O [ábaco](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81baco) era um dispositivo de computação (uma pena não ser mais usado nas escolas, deve ser por isso que as pessoas não conseguem mais fazer uma simples conta de porcentagem), mas ele não possui uma linguagem de programação, não há como expressar funções matemáticas nele. O mesmo vale para todas as máquinas mecânicas e até algumas eletromecânicas até a década de 40 (do século 20, vai que isto sobreviva umas 3 ou 4 décadas e as pessoas do futuro se confundam :) ).

O computador moderno surgiu durante uma rápida evolução durante a segunda guerra mundial (sempre o uso militar sendo a força por todo empurrão na tecnologia). Ali surgiu o computador que conseguia fazer todo tipo de cálculo de forma abstrata, automática e principalmente programável, ainda que de uma forma rudimentar.

É possível que outras máquinas possam ter tido a capacidade de programação, mas por não ter outras características ficaram menos famosas, acabaram sendo relegadas a um galho da evolução que não foram pra frente.

A representação do programa era manual e não tenho referências de como faziam. Sei que era inserido por chaves através de codificação binária, mas provavelmente havia algo em um nível mais alto sendo realizado no papel antes de chegar nisso.

Já havia uma linguagem de programação de baixo nível nesse dispositivo. E provavelmente já usavam outra linguagem antes.

## Primeiras linguagens

Ficou claro na época que linguagens de maior nível eram necessárias. [O Assembly logo foi inventado e depois montadores para converter este código em algo mais baixo nível](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101). Principalmente depois que a entrada de dados pôde ser feita de forma mais conveniente do que chaves binárias, como a leitura de cartão perfurado através de uma máquina de escrever adaptada.

Depois surgiram linguagens que começaram se aproximar da notação usada na matemática e o uso do inglês. [Fortran](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran) foi a primeira que tinha boa organização e fez sucesso por ser um claro passo à frente.

Veja o [*timeline* da criação das linguagens de programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_programming_languages) (melhor esforço possível).

## Componentes necessários

Vou correr o risco de errar aqui, estou falando algo que eu vejo acontecer e não estou seguindo uma definição formal. Então para resolver qualquer problema computacional é preciso ser capaz de:

- armazenar - e ler obviamente - dados em um lugar qualquer pelo menos de forma transitória - manter estado (não é I/O);
- transformar dados de forma a expressar as operações matemáticas mais simples (eu diria que a adição e multiplicação na sua forma mais básica são necessárias);
- manter um sequência de "execução" - organizar logicamente os armazenamentos e transformações;
- desviar a sequência;
- tomar uma decisão entre pelo menos 2 "caminhos".

Posso ter esquecido de alguma coisa ou posso ter colocado algo que já é uma abstração de outra citada.

Algumas pessoas podem dizer que as três últimas podem ser definidas como ter a capacidade de recursão. É uma forma de dizer, mas não sei se todo mundo entenderá isto. E não sei se isso já não é abstrair um pouco o conceito.

Não é à toa que as linguagens que fazem sucesso são as imperativas, mesmo que elas carreguem algum outro paradigma para auxiliar.

Mais informações em:

- [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101)
- [O Excel é uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/99642/101)
- [HTML é uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101)
- [A primeira linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156521/101)
- [Como é desenvolvida uma linguagem de programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101)
- [O que é a Máquina de Turing?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/158043/101)
- [Debate sobre Completeza Turing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TuringComplete)
- [O filme](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2084970/) :D

[image: Máquina d Turing]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quem negativou pode dizer se tem alguma coisa errada na resposta?

Comment: Tenho algumas discordâncias quanto ao item 2 (se o meu entendimento foi o que ele realmente teve como intenção expressar), pois com o sistema de numeração unário é possível escrever a operação de soma e, dela, multiplicação e subtração.

Comment: O que é um sistema de numeração unário? Mostre como fazer.

Comment: **O que é unário?** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system?wprov=sfsi1 ; **Mostre como fazer** vou precisar de um pouco de paciência, o melhor exemplo é com máquina de Turing, faço (ou procuro uma MT com esse fim) assim que chegar em casa

Comment: Eu pensei no binário que tem utilidade prática pra falar em linguagem de programação real e não apenas conceitual. Na prática as operações básicas com binários são a adição e multiplicação, as outras são derivadas, então pode ser que conceitualmente funcione, mas novamente não é prático.

Comment: existe algoritmo de soma em binário também, que é melhor escrever como máquina de Turing. Eu pus essa discordância em uma edição de resposta minha (é tanto que esqueci de mudar o interlocutor de "o autor original" para "você"). Como você tratou de Turing completude, é importante ressaltar conceitos. Novamente, não é prático, assim como uma MT faria operações demais para tarefas simples de um passo.

Answer (score 3):

Da fonte comum (Wikipedia) tem uma resposta bem simples:

> Uma linguagem de programação é um método padronizado para comunicar
>   instruções para um computador.

Ou seja, se de alguma forma você se comunica com o computador de forma organizada ,já se esta usando uma linguagem de programação. Lembre-se que existem **tipos** ou **classificações** de linguagens, e algumas delas não possuem compilador, mas ainda se comunicam com o computador(Interpretadas).

Answer (score 1):

> "Linguagem de programação é um conceito mais abstrato, são as regras
>   especificadas que regem como um código deve se comportar para produzir
>   programas de computador. A linguagem não é um programa que executa."
>    -Trecho utilizado por @Maniero [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101691/o-que-%C3%A9-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ide-e-compilador?lq=1);
>
> "- Programação: Linguagens que usam a lógica humana para solucionar problemas diversos usando comandos mais complexos como. SE ( if ),
>   Então ( then), faça ( do ), para ( for ).
>
> Exemplo de linguagens de programação é JAVA, PHP, JAVASCRIPT,C++ e
>   Pascal."
>   http://progplay.blogspot.com.br/2013/03/linguagem-de-marcacao-x-linguagem-de.html

Em uma resposta mais pessoal, não creio que seja correto afirmar que é uma linguagem de PROGRAMAÇÃO, por conter código fonte, sintaxe...isso o HTML tem, e HTML não é uma linguagem de programação porém, contem código fonte e devemos obedecer uma sintaxe. A Linguagem de programação deve possuir lógica e realizar processamento (calculos, conversões, manipular dados)