# Quais aplicações Ruby tem além da web?

Tags: ruby, framework, biblioteca

Tenho vontade de me aprofundar em Ruby, pela facilidade da linguagem, assim como Python, que por exemplo, na minha Universidade utilizam muito para aplicações matemáticas e científicas.

Vejo muito a utilização de Ruby com Rails para Web, mas gostaria de saber se Ruby está sendo utilizado em outras áreas/aplicações.

Quais *frameworks* e bibliotecas que não são para web?

Realmente falou em Ruby, falou em web? Ou o cenário é diferente?

Comment: Eu só uso Ruby para criar programas desktop, com interface grafica e tudo.
Tipo se você baixar o Ruby e instalar, pode já começar a programar pra desktop. Ele executa no prompt de comando. Já pra criar sites, acho que você precisa fazer algo mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualquer [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) pode ser usada para qualquer atividade. É claro que algumas são melhores para um tipo de aplicação do que outras.

Existem algumas linguagens que optaram por ser de nicho mesmo e são muito boas nisso. Um exemplo é [R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) que é adequada para estatísticas.

Mas a imensa maioria das linguagens optam por ser de uso geral por atingir um público maior. É claro que elas não costumam ser melhores que as outras em nada, são apenas razoavelmente boas em tudo, é o caso de Ruby.

O que muitas vezes determina um uso um pouco maior da linguagem não é a linguagem em si, mas as plataformas onde ela começa ser usada ou as bibliotecas existentes para ela.

Exemplos claros do primeiro caso são JavaScript, que foi usada em todos os navegadores e até padronizado, e Lua, que foi escolhida por muitos jogos como linguagem de personalização.

No segundo caso Ruby é o melhor exemplo onde a biblioteca determinou o sucesso e nicho da linguagem. Tem gente que acha que a linguagem se chama [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/).

Mas a realidade é que Ruby pode ser usada para qualquer coisa que não exija performance ao extremo. Ruby não é conhecida por ser uma linguagem rápida. E por mais que surjam ferramentas para torná-la mais rápida, sempre haverá limitações, nunca poderá competir com linguagens de tipagem estática, só para ficar no exemplo mais óbvio.

Não sei como está o suporte de Ruby nos dispositivos móveis. Acredito que seja fraco ou inexistente. Isso pode mudar, mas duvido que ainda tenha espaço para Ruby ser forte nisto. Note que mesmo que suporte completamente será por responsabilidade de bibliotecas e não da linguagem.

Quer fazer aplicações GUI/Desktop? Ok. Ruby suporta através de bibliotecas existentes, tais como: [Shoes](http://shoesrb.com/), [FXRuby](http://www.fxruby.org/), [QtRuby](https://techbase.kde.org/Languages/Ruby), etc.

Quer mais? Pesquise em [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/) e [Ruby Gems](https://rubygems.org/). Tem literalmente milhares de bibliotecas, a maioria não é para web.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Exatamente o que eu estava procurando, obrigado pela resposta :D

Comment: Só um ponto que faltou, ruby vem sendo muito utilizado para escrever testes, diversas ferramentas utilizam Ruby como linguagem, um exemplo seria o calabash que foi escrito em Ruby. Abraço.