# É possível considerar a Linden Scripting Language uma linguagem de programação robusta?

Tags: eventos

A LSL é uma linguagem de programação orientada a eventos que é utilizada dentro do Second Life. É possível considera-la uma linguagem de programação adequada aos princípios de Turing? O desenvolvimento de obras interessantes (mesmo que sejam dentro do ambiente do Second Life) pode acontecer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não conheço a fundo LSL, mas pela descrição na [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linden_Scripting_Language), você define nela uma máquina de estados finitos, definindo que computação é feita em cada estado.

Se não me engano, turing completude é definido por cinco características :

1. Capacidade de ler valores de variáveis
2. Capacidade de escrever valores em variáveis
3. Laços/desvio incondicional
4. Estrutura de decisão
5. Capacidade de realizar operações com as variáveis lidas/armazenadas

(*citation needed*, eu vi na aula de computabilidade uns sete anos atrás).

Assim, ainda mais visto que não vi nada que proíba recursão em LSL, creio que ela seja turing completa. Um teste "simples" é tentar escrever um interpretador de máquina de turing.

#### EDIT

Não confunda linguagem de programação robusta com linguagem turing completa. Brainfuck é turing completa, mas nem por isso ela pode ser considerada robusta como uma linguagem para uso comercial.

#### EDIT 2

Mais sobre completude Turing [nessa resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107182/64969). Trecho que achei interessante da resposta dele para essa pergunta em particular:

> - armazenar - e ler obviamente - dados em um lugar qualquer pelo menos de forma transitória - manter estado (não é I/O);
> - transformar dados de forma a expressar as operações matemáticas mais simples (eu diria que a adição e multiplicação na sua forma mais básica são necessárias);
> - manter um sequência de "execução" - organizar logicamente os armazenamentos e transformações;
> - desviar a sequência;
> - tomar uma decisão entre pelo menos 2 "caminhos".

Tenho algumas discordâncias quanto ao item 2 (se o meu entendimento foi o que ele realmente teve como intenção expressar), pois com o sistema de numeração unário é possível escrever a operação de soma e, dela, multiplicação e subtração.