# Diferença de sintaxe entre banco de dados

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, postgresql, oracle

Qual a diferença, na sintaxe, dos seguintes bancos de dados, para uma consulta simples, do tipo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id = '1' ORDER BY nome GROUP BY nome LIMIT 1
```

Ou, o que eles diferem entre si na sintaxe em geral? Ou é tudo a mesma coisa?

#### Bancos:

- Oracle
- MySQL
- SQL Server
- PostgreSQL

Não precisa explicar a sintaxe de cada banco. Um *apanhado* geral seria ótimo, só para ter uma noção.

Comment: acredito que só irá mudar a sintaxe do limit, sendo TOP X pro SQL Server, os outros acredito que continua sendo LIMIT X

Comment: O `Oracle` [não suporta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering) `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma coisa chamada [SQL ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

ANSI é uma entidade de padronização do Estados Unidos, equivalente a ABNT nossa.

Na verdade, existe uma entidade chamado ISO que é a entidade padronizadora mundial. Em geral padronizações mundial são submetidas por entidades nacionais ou macro regionais e se aprovado pelo corpo dos demais padronizadores se torna um padrão que todos devem seguir.

Apesar de comumente chamarmos de SQL ANSI, o SQL é padronizado pela ISO também. Então qualquer produto deveria seguir fielmente o que o padrão diz. Seria melhor chamar de SQL padrão.

Em muitas linguagens isso ocorre. Em SQL nunca ocorreu.

O fato é que não há nenhum produto que implemente todo o padrão SQL moderno. Até existe quem faça isto baseado em uma padronização antiga, a [SQL-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) por exemplo. E obviamente vários produtos colocam coisas que não existe no padrão para seu produto se destacar. A mais recente quando escrevi esta resposta era a [SQL:2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2016).

Isso se torna um problema porque um dia padroniza-se uma forma e esse produto não pode mais se conformar com o padrão.

Alguns produtos na verdade nunca ligaram para o padrão. Nunca acharam que isso era importante. Na verdade, é bom para eles porque prende o cliente no produto deles. Alguns acham que eles é que devem ditar o que o padrão deve ter. Alguns enganam provendo a sintaxe que não faz nada.

Existe dificuldade em implementar certas características do SQL. Em alguns o problema é a interpretação do que está no padrão. Embora a sintaxe possa ser a mesma, a semântica não é. Tem casos que o produto não se comporta bem com o padrão.

Para o básico tudo funciona igual, pelo menos na sintaxe, se não fosse assim o produto não teria a vantagem de dizer que usa SQL e que você aprendendo a linguagem já sabe usá-lo.

Neste caso `SELECT`, `FROM`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` e `GROUP BY` são padrões mesmo. `LIMIT` é respeitado por quase todos os produtos. Mas tem produto que não permite limitar ou usa outra sintaxe, o caso mais óbvio é o SQL Server que usa `TOP` como palavra-chave. Tem produto que estende a sintaxe do `LIMIT`.

Na verdade, a sintaxe é o de menos. A semântica diferente, a forma de otimizar, e outros detalhes do produto tem muito mais importância. A mesma sintaxe pode dar resultados diferentes ou ter performance absurdamente diferente em produtos diferentes.

Por isso que é uma bobagem essas *frameworks* que tentam abstrair os vários SGDBs, ainda mais os que tentam fazer isto quando aceitam filosofias bem diferentes. Resolver a sintaxe é fácil, mas isto não é o mais importante.

SQL é uma das coisas mais mal-criadas e conduzidas na computação, como tudo que é criado por comitês, um dos motivos de ninguém se conformar integralmente.

Note que [SQL não é uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101), pelo menos não na sua forma básica original. Com algumas extensões a ela pode fazer o todo ser uma linguagem de programação e muitos produtos fazem isto pelo menos para suas *procedures*. Na verdade, já [mostraram que é possível mesmo SQL padrão mais moderno ser uma linguagem de programação](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set), mas depende da implementação e tem que fazer coisas malucas para conseguir o resultado.

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Comment: +1, em especial pelo comentário sobre frameworks. A abstração acaba fazendo você perder todas as particularidades boas, e ficando com a "sobra" que funciona (mais ou menos) igual em todos.

Comment: Muito bom! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Há uma diferença. Vale a pena pesquisar no manual do usuário que disponibilizam na web.

No SQL Server a consulta mencionada fica da seguinte forma.
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tabela

ou seja o limit não vai no Where o TOP vai no select com a quantidade de linhas que deseja retornar