# Qual a linguagem web é utilizada em sites para fazer efeitos?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Como os desenvolvedores produzem estes sites com tantos efeitos e toda modernidade? São linguagens especificas? *Frameworks*? *Plugins*?

Exemplos:

http://www.bomeapp.com/

http://www.sauto.com.br/site/

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 5):

As únicas linguagens consideradas padrões da web são o [HTML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101) (5 é a versão mais nova), [CSS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101) (3 é a versão mais nova) e [JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46983/101) ([EcmaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) 11 é a versão mais nova em 2020). E todas as páginas são ou deveriam ser feitas só usando elas (isto já não é mais verdade, pode-se usar outras linguagens de programação que não JS/ES). Inclusive é o caso dos sites citados e pode ser visto no fonte da página que está sempre aberto.

Note que a versão mais nova [nem sempre pode ser usada em todos navegadores](http://caniuse.com/).

Cuidado para não começar aprendendo coisas erradas. Cuidado com o marketing. Cuidado com a superficialidade. Cuidado com o uso indiscriminado dos *frameworks*.

Não use nada que seja fora do padrão. Vai tirando suas dúvidas específicas aqui. Dê uma lida  nas *tags* destas linguagens, tem informações adicionais. Acompanhe todos os *links* passados. Tenha dedicação e comprometimento.

No lado do servidor que não é o foco da pergunta pode usar virtualmente qualquer linguagem de programação, embora algumas façam mais sucesso. [PHP](https://secure.php.net/) é uma delas, mas muitos programadores preferem outras, como [C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou [Java](https://www.oracle.com/java/index.html), só para ficar nas mais populares.

Comment: bjgown mas como eu posso aplicar os efeitos para que meus sites tenham um design semelhante aos dos sites citados?? Agradeço :)

Comment: Pra responder isto tenho que escrever uma coleção de livros. Vai aprendendo e comece fazer perguntas específicas, bem específicas, conforme vai encontrando dificuldades.