# Transformar um código JavaScript em HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Fiz um *banner* no site bannersnack para ser usado no MercadoLivre, o site da opção de baixar o *banner* em GIF, PNG, JPG E HTML5 e disponibiliza o código em JavaScript também.

O GIF da certo coloca-lo no MercadoLivre, entretanto ele perde a animação, PNG E JPG não serve, pois o banner é de dois slides, já HTML5 não tenho nem ideia de como funciona.

O MercadoLivre aceita apenas HTML, eles não aceitam linguagem em JavaScript na descrição do anúncio

Será que tem alguma forma de converter esse *banner* em JavaScript para HTML sem perder as animação?

Comment: converter automatico eu acredito que não, mas voce pode usar GIF ou criar o seu proprio usando CSS3 e Html.

Comment: @AltiarliSilva não entendi qual seria o problema de por um GIF animado. Você diz que ao subir o GIF ele perde a animação no ML, ou você está com dificuldade pra baixar o GIF animado?

Comment: O GIF roda normal, é de dois slides, só que tem uma animação dentro dos slides, essa animação que perde quando baixo o banner em GIF, segue o link para você ver do banner: http://share.bannersnack.com/FFFBA6D569B/bxcs6i5jo

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Esqueça. O MercardoLivre tem um bom motivo não só para bloquear a animação do GIF, mas também o JavaScript e recursos HTML mais poderosos que permitam fazer coisas mais elaboradas. Qualquer tentativa provavelmente violaria os termos de uso.

Mesmo que este não fosse o problema, ainda seria muito complicado fazer o que deseja (dependendo do que for até pode ser possível). [HTML não é uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101). O JavaScript existe justamente por causa disto.

Faça o que dá para fazer em HTML básico, e consulte a documentação deles para ver o que mais pode ser usado. E aprenda o que é permitido. É possível fazer algumas coisas mais sofisticadas mas é necessário aprender usar estas tecnologias permitidas. Faça perguntas mais específicas para cada problema que encontrar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Bigown. Mas o quão complicado seria fazer o que desejo?

Comment: No caso já vi vendedores fazerem o inimaginável na descrição só com html, como vi em outro fórum, existe maneiras de bular o sistema, não traria problemas a não ser que alguém denunciasse o anúncio caso percebesse, e acredite, ninguém liga.

Comment: Se quer fazer animações, esquece, é tudo o que o ML não quer nas páginas deles. Aí você tem que fazer perguntas específicas. De qualquer forma qualquer coisa que seja para burlar algo, eu tô fora.

Comment: Entendo, mas animações em GIF eles permitem, até comercializam templates animados, oque não aceitam é o javascrip, se de alguma forma você conseguir fazer animações apenas com html, um banner no meu caso, não estarei infringindo regra nenhuma, pois eles aceitam html, tem uma opção justamente para isso na descrição. De qualquer forma eu agradeço, realmente devemos ter cuidado no que é permitido ou não, mas não custa nada tentar não é mesmo?  No máximo eles irão pausar o anúncio até a regularização do mesmo como já aconteceu comigo com outro tipo problema que não vem ao caso.

Comment: Dá para fazer alguma coisa com HTML/CSS, mas tem que fazer perguntas específicas sobre o que quer. Se pedir para as pessoas fazerem tudo para você, aqui não rola.

Comment: Entendo, o problema é que não entendo praticamente nada de programação, queria saber se tinha como mesmo e encontrar alguém que fizesse para mim, pagaria pelo serviço, você conhece alguém conseguiria fazer isso para mim? Segue o link do banner para ter uma idéia: http://share.bannersnack.com/FFFBA6D569B/bxcs6i5jo

Comment: Código: <script type="text/javascript">
var bannersnack_embed = {"hash":"bxcs6i5jo","width":900,"height":400,"t":1450372978,"userId":21929791,"https":true,"type":"html5"};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdns.snacktools.net/bannersnack/embed.js"></script>

Comment: Aqui não é local para isto, aqui só esclarecemos dúvidas de programação claras, focadas e objetivas.

Comment: Tranquilo, me desculpe. Obrigado pela informações, no caso até da para fazer algo com HTML/CSS, irei procurar alguém que entenda dessas paradas para fazer para mim. Obrigado amigo, tenha uma ótima tarde!