# Less é uma linguagem de programação, ou apenas algo mais complexo do CSS?

Tags: característica-linguagem, less

Bom eu acredito que o Less talvez não possa ser uma linguagem de programação, então o que ele é? onde se classifica?

Se ele for realmente uma linguagem de programação o que o faz ser?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101 se não me engano já foi fechada e removia pergunta sobre outras coisas que são claramente linguagem de marcação como duplicata desta. Isto dá uma visão gera~odo que é uma linguagem de programação: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LESS é uma [linguagem de folhas de estilo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) dinâmica, mas não uma linguagem de programação - pois não é *[Turing-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)*.

Suas principais características são:

- Variáveis

  ```
  @pale-green-color: #4D926F; // Definição de variável

  #header {
    color: @pale-green-color; // utilização de variável
  }
  h2 {
    color: @pale-green-color;
  }
  ```
- Mixins

  ```
  .rounded-corners (@radius: 5px 10px 8px 2px) { // Definição da primitiva
    -webkit-border-radius: @radius;
    -moz-border-radius: @radius;
    border-radius: @radius;
  }

  #header {
    .rounded-corners; // Utilização da primitiva
  }
  ```
- Estilo em [aninhamento](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub-rotina_aninhada)

  ```
  .header {
      p {
          font-size: 16px              // compilado como .header p {...}
          a {
              text-decoration: none;   // compilado como .header p a {...}
              &:hover {
                  border-width: 1px;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Browsers não intepretam LESS. Um arquivo LESS deve ser interpretado quando o código estiver pronto para o ambiente-alvo, e o resultado da interpretação é um arquivo CSS padrão que é então disponibilizado para consumo.

[Fonte.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(stylesheet_language))

Comment: As linguagens de programação não tem obrigatoriamente que ser turing complete.

Comment: @BrunoCosta ainda assim esta é a definição mais aceita. Como foge ao escopo (já que LESS não se enquadra em nenhum dos casos-limite) eu preferi a abordagem simples. Para mais detalhes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/102452/o-que-caracteriza-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 1):

LESS **não é uma linguagem de programação** e sim um pré processador CSS assim como SASS.

O intuito do LESS é estender as capacidades do CSS, adicionando novos recursos para gerar CSS como *mixins*, *functions* e *variáveis* - todos recursos inexistentes em CSS.

O processador LESS se encarrega de transformar seu código LESS em CSS puro para que seja utilizado da maneira usual.

Tendo dúvidas sobre as características de uma linguagem de programação, visite o link contido no comentário do @Maniero em seu *post*.

Answer (score 0):

LESS é referenciado como uma linguagem, ele gera o CSS partindo de uma lógica. LESS gera CSS assim como PHP termina em HTML.
Não podemos negar que ele é mais complexo, mas em prol de menos código para fazer mais além de termos menos refação.
Você pode encontrar mais detalhes sobre as funcionalidades que pode utilizar nos próprios exemplos da documentação no link abaixo.

http://lesscss.org/features/