# Qual marcação html para menu, que consome menos recursos do browser?

Tags: css, html5, desempenho

Abaixo uma versão simplificada da marcação HTML de um menu que utilizo:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" title="Teste X">Teste X</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Teste Y">Teste Y</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Teste Z">Teste Z</a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#" title="Teste ZA">Teste ZA</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" title="Teste ZB">Teste ZB</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" title="Teste ZC">Teste ZC</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Estou pensando em remover o `text` das tags `a` e utilizar o CSS `content` para renderizar o `text` das tags `a` com base no atributo `title`.

Nesta segunda marcação, deverá ser incluindo no CSS:

```
a:after{ content: attr(title); }
```

E o HTML ficaria desta forma:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" title="Teste X"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Teste Y"></a></li>
   <li><a href="#" title="Teste Z"></a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#" title="Teste ZA"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#" title="Teste ZB"></a></li>
           <li><a href="#" title="Teste ZC"></a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

A segunda versão tem o HTML nitidamente menor, mas não sei se consome mais ou menos recursos do browser.

A aplicação em que estou trabalhando é muito grande, com muito JavaScript, e preciso otimizar o máximo possível, a fim melhorar a performance e reduzir custos de processamento e memória no browser.

**O que preciso saber é:**

Desconsiderando o tempo de download, quais os prós e contras de cada uma das duas implementações acima em termos de processamento, memória RAM ou outras variáveis de performance?

Comment: Sinceramente.... os recursos são ínfimos....
Entenda que... `CSS` e `HTML` são apenas [linguagens de marcação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35547/html-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o), o browser vai apenas ler elas e "pintar" na tela. Se possuir algum `javaScript` embutido, ai são outros quinhentos...

Comment: A aplicação em que estou trabalhando é muito grande e preciso otimizar o máximo possível, a fim melhorar a performance e custos de processamento e memória no browser.

Comment: Uma renderização complexa com HTML e CSS pode ser absurdamente mais custoso do que um JS. Eu acho que esse caso não faz diferença perceptível e é micro-otimização que por definição é desnecessária. Mas não sou especialista nesse assunto. Alguma coisa me diz que o segundo irá atrasar a apresentação, mas posso estar desatualizado.

Comment: Talvez isso ajude: http://blog.caelum.com.br/por-uma-web-mais-rapida-26-tecnicas-de-otimizacao-de-sites

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, agradeço a intenção, mas conheço um pouco sobre as boas práticas e na pergunta estou desconsiderando o tempo de download. Realmente estou interessado em como mensurar a performance, processamento e memória.

Comment: "A aplicação em que estou trabalhando é muito grande, com muito JavaScript, e preciso otimizar o máximo possível..." Na parte do Javascript acredito que seja mais fácil de analisar o consumo de recursos, pois é uma Linguagem de Programação. Recomendo dar uma lida em [Análise de Algorítmos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/An%C3%A1lise_de_algoritmos). Questões como Ordem Assintótica e Big O podem ser aplicadas ao Javascript, com os resultados você pode estudar melhores implementações.

Comment: També não sou um expert, mas tenderia a concordar com o @bigown, não parece muito relevante.