# Por quê nem todo if pode ter else?

Tags: vhdl

Estou explorando um pouco sobre FPGA e queria fazer algo bem simplório, um botão que quando clicado iria mudar o `status`.

Ignorando os outros problemas na lógica em si, o fato que me chamou atenção foi que isso nem sequer "compila":

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
   status <= '1';
else 
   status <= '0';
end if;
```

Isso me retorna um erro:

> [Synth 8-27] else clause after check for clock not supported

Além de outros dois erros:

> [Synth 8-285] failed synthesizing module 'out'
>   [Common 17-69] Command failed: Synthesis failed - please see the console or run log file for details

*Estou usando um Xilinx Artix-7, usando o Vivado 2017.1, se isto for algo importante.*

---

Isso é totalmente estranho, sempre parti do principio que todo `if` poderia de ter um `else`, mas parece que não assim.

**Por quê isso ocorre? E em quais outras condições o `else` não pode ser utilizado?**

Comment: É estranho se pensar como programa, mas não como circuito. O `rising_edge` irá monitorar as transições de subida do `clk` e, pensando logicamente, o `else` desta condição seria qualquer estado senão a transição de subida, inclusive o `clk` em nível lógico 1. Idealmente, o tempo de transição é 0 e, assim, o sinal `status` ficaria em 1 por um tempo igual a 0, o que não faz muito sentido. Qual é sua intenção com o código? No caso, o que seria `status`?

Comment: A minha ideia em geral seria que quando clicasse no botão o FPGA iria parar a alimentação do Arduino, por um curtíssimo espaço de tempo, por isso a primeira ideia foi o `else`. Estou pensando agora em usar alguns "interruptores" para que consiga aumentar ou diminuir o tempo, o botão apenas cortará a energia pelo tempo definido no interruptor. O objetivo é  fazer algum Fault Attack/Glitch Attack, de maneira que cortar/reduzir a energia de alimentação num período curto o suficiente para que o processador do Arduino pule alguma instrução, nem sei se isso funcionará no final de tudo, mas é isso.

Comment: é bem comum você fazer o tratamento do botão através de um contador para buscar eliminar o ruído mecânico. Se quiser posso completar a pergunta com um código assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe algum complicadores a mais na questão de "ler" um botão que irão interferir no resultado, principalmente o *deboucing* para eliminar ruídos mecânicos do botão, mas não irei entrar nestes detalhes na resposta.

Para mais informações: [Debounce Logic Circuit (with VHDL example)](https://www.eewiki.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4980758)

Como comentei, essa estranheza é causada sempre que você tenta analisar o código VHDL como um programa e não como um circuito eletrônico (motivo este que [afirmei na minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/216032/vhdl-%C3%A9-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o/216082#216082) que VHDL não deve ser considerada linguagem de programação). Fazer o trecho de código abaixo:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
    status <= '1';
else
     status <= '0';
end if;
```

Não faz muito sentido quando analisado o circuito que isso deveria gerar. Basicamente o código está dizendo: o sinal `status` deve receber o valor `'1'` sempre que houver uma transição positiva no sinal `clk` e em todos os outros casos deve receber `'0'`. Quando o sinal `clk` estabiliza em `'1'` após a transição já irá caracterizar um *outro caso*, entrando no `else`; isto é, idealmente o tempo de transição do sinal é 0, então o sinal `status` ficaria no nível lógico alto por um tempo igual a 0. O sintetizador não consegue entender isso e gera o erro.

Para facilitar mais a visualização, podemos desenhar, de fato, o circuito. Quando você deseja alterar o estado de um sinal com base na alteração de estado de outro sinal você estará trabalhando com registradores. Ou seja, a parte do `if` geraria o seguinte circuito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que nada mais é que um registrador que atribui o valor `'1'` ao sinal `status` sempre que houver a transição positiva em `clk`. Perceba que não existe um meio de gerar um circuito que seja a negação da expressão `rising_edge` para gerar o circuito do `else`, e considerando que o tempo de duração do valor `'1'` seria 0 nesta situação, ele ficaria igual a `'0'` sempre, o que *geraria* o circuito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que não faz sentido, pois o sinal `status` iria receber dois valores distintos, `'1'` e `'0'`, em toda transição positiva de `clk`.

Mas é interessante notar que isso ocorre principalmente quando você está tratando as transições no `if`. Se tratar apenas o valor, geralmente o sintetizador irá compreender o que deseja fazer e irá sintetizar o circuito adequado. Um exemplo **bem simples** de um botão seria verificar, a cada transição positiva do `clk`, se o nível lógico do botão é 0¹ e, quando for, definir o valor de `status` para `'1'`.

```
process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if button = '0' then
            status <= '1';
        else
            status <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

O circuito gerado por este código é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba que o circuito gerado será apenas um *flip-flop* tipo D em que a entrada será o valor negado de `button` e a saída será `status`. Se você fizer a simulação, verá que o valor de `status` sempre será `'1'` enquanto `button` for `'0'` (pressionado), onde as transições de `status` será síncrona em relação a `clk` devido ao registrador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que o sinal `status` é alterado para `'1'` somente na transição positiva de `clk` após `button` estar em `'0'` justamente por ser síncrono em relação a `clk`. O mesmo acontece no final, quando `status` é alterado para `0`.

**Notas:**

1. Considerei que o botão está pressionado como sendo nível lógico 0 pois essa é a implementação mais comum nas placas de desenvolvimento (circuito *pull-down*).

Answer (score 0):

O problema não está na sintaxe do `if/else` e sim no operador de comparação `<=` que você está utilizando no lugar do operador de atribuição `:=`, que tal:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
   status := '1';
else 
   status := '0';
end if;
```

Comment: Isso somente se  `status` for uma variável do processo. Se for um sinal da entidade, o operador está correto. E mesmo sendo uma variável, esse `if` não faz sentido, assim como comentei na pergunta. Finalizando, `<=` não é um operador de comparação neste caso.