# Existe alguma forma de trazer informações do banco de dados sem utilizar linguagem server side?

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, json, xml

Eu estava avaliando o site do [Zap Imoveis](http://www.zapimoveis.com.br) para saber quais linguagens e tecnologias utilizadas no site deles. Utilizo o [Wappalyzer](https://wappalyzer.com), uma extensão do Google Chrome, que mostra as tecnologias usadas em qualquer site.

Bem, eu verifiquei que no referido site o Wappalyzer não mostrou nenhuma linguagem *server side*, dei uma olhada no código com as ferramentas do desenvolvedor no Google Chrome e também não percebi nada. O Único *framework* que percebi foi o Bootstrap.

Acredito que seja necessária alguma linguagem *server side* para trazer os imóveis cadastrados do banco de dados para serem mostrado no *frontend*, ou estou enganado?

Existe alguma forma de trazer as informações do banco de dados no servidor para serem mostrados no site de alguma outra forma sem utilizar alguma linguagem *server side*? Como XML ou JSON? E como seria?

Qual seria a forma mais eficiente (tempo de carregamento de uma quantidade grande de dados para as páginas do site) de mostrar uma quantidade grande de dados do BD no *frontend*.

Comment: Se pudesse fazer conexão ao banco de dados via client-side, qualquer um poderia ver a senha e ter acesso ao seu banco.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não existe. Qualquer problema de computação precisa ser programado com uma [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101).

Na verdade a questão surgiu porque está usando ferramentas inadequadas para realizar uma atividade. Você caiu no conto do "compre este produto e veja todo mundo sem roupa". Não existe isto a não ser que a pessoa queria ser vista sem roupa. Existem maneiras de se obter informações de quem quer que elas sejam dadas, não de quem quer esconder.

[XML ou JSON sequer são linguagens de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/101). Sem uma linguagem de programação que faça isto apenas se o banco de dados fornecer o dado pronto neste formato (sem processar nada, vem bruto o que já está gravado no banco de dados), mas de qualquer forma seria temerário dar acesso direto ao banco de dados.

Comment: Entendi, Bigow! Muito esclarecedor. Mas a minha questão central é: eu consigo usar XML ou JSON para trazer as informações de um banco de dados no servidor para meu frontend?

Comment: Você gastou a maior parte do texto falando de outra coisa e mesmo isto a resposta é que não tem o que fazer, vai pelo caminho que todo mundo faz.

Comment: @HebsonAraujo , XML e JSON são formas de representação de dados. Eles podem ser usados como forma de comunicação entre dois sistemas, mas mesmo assim precisa de sistema em ambos os lados