# O Blade do Laravel é uma linguagem de programação?

Tags: php, laravel, característica-linguagem, laravel-blade

Após uma breve discussão de porquê o [HTML não é uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/35547/html-%C3%A9-uma-linguagem-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o?rq=1), caracterizamos que não porque ele não é capaz de realizar cálculos, tomar decisões, mudar informações contidas em algum tipo de memória, etc.

O Blade é a linguagem utilizada pelo Laravel para construção de *views*. Ele contém as instruções começadas com um `@`, por exemplo o `@if`, `@section`, `@for`, etc. O mesmo utiliza expressões do Laravel e do PHP para funcionar.

Blade também tem variáveis, porém você não as declara diretamente nele. Ele recebe as variáveis pelo controlador, e você pode acessar com `{{ }}`.

Esse é um exemplo de um Blade:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        @if (isset($mensagem))
             <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $mensagem }}</div>
        @else
             <div class="alert alert-primary">Tudo funcional.</div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

O Blade acima foi capaz de entender se a variável `$mensagem` existe ou não. Tomou uma decisão.

Isso torna o Blade do Laravel uma linguagem de programação?

Comment: Uma das necessidades de uma linguagem de programação é _"mudar informações contidas em algum tipo de memória;"_, se ele apenas acessa a memória mas não a altera, acredito que não seja (por pouco). Não sou especialista então deixarei as respostas pra quem entende

Comment: @Costamilam então, o fato dela ler, mas não criar, me confunde um pouco. Apesar que, com `<?php $variavel = 123 ?>` você declara, e brevemente poderá ler no Blade. Mas aí você já está utilizando o PHP diretamente, mas logo o Blade também é PHP indireto. Eu não sei.

Comment: Você pode colocar CSS inline nas tags HTML ou dentro do `<style>`, mas continua sendo linguagens separadas. E como o Woss disse, _"PHP é uma linguagem de programação ou um superset de C?"_ assim como o Blade é do PHP. Depende da sua definição do que é uma linguagem de programação

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eu dei uma olhada por cima na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade) e pelo que pude perceber é *turing complete*, portanto é uma linguagem de programação, assim como qualquer linguagem de *template* bem completa. O que me fez considerar assim é que tem armazenamento de estado, capacidade de fazer algumas manipulações de dados e controle de fluxo.

É claro que ela deve ser uma camada fina em cima do PHP, mas não deixa de ter "vida própria" mesmo sendo uma [transpilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/189894/101). E não vou considerar que o fato dela poder injetar PHP dentro dê a capacidade total porque aí não é obter o resultado por meios próprios e sim delegando para uma outra linguagem.

Nos comentários se questionou que ela não guarda valor, mas o que é isto na documentação?

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Engine/Blade.php).

Está criando uma variável, guardando valor nela, mudando este valor e verificando-o. A não ser que tenha algo errado que eu não sei ela permite fazer tudo o que uma máquina computacional precisa.

Comment: Por isso deixei pra outra pessoa :) boa resposta

Comment: Eu só não disse que é uma boa linguagem de programação :P :) HTML+CSS tb é uma linguagem de programação se vc considerar as duas como uma coisa só, mas...

Comment: Esse parte: `capacidade de fazer algumas manipulações de dados`? não entendi isso direito, você está querendo dizer que o `blade` de certo modo é limitado? (eu só gostaria de entender) visto que o `blade` você consegue escrever código e com isso fazer qualquer manipulação.

Comment: Eu não falei em limitação, eu só não sei toda capacidade que ele tem, mas tem o suficiente para ser uma linguagem de programação. Porém limitado ele deve ser em algum nível, tudo é, nada tem poder ilimitado.